# Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?

Tags: git, export, git-archive, svn-export

I've been wondering whether there is a good "git export" solution that creates a copy of a tree without the `.git` repository directory. There are at least three methods I know of:

1. `git clone` followed by removing the `.git` repository directory.
2. [`git checkout-index`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html) alludes to this functionality but starts with "Just read the desired tree into the index..." which I'm not entirely sure how to do.
3. [`git-export`](http://code.google.com/p/git-export/) is a third-party script that essentially does a `git clone` into a temporary location followed by `rsync --exclude='.git'` into the final destination.

None of these solutions really strike me as being satisfactory. The closest one to `svn export` might be option 1, because both require the target directory to be empty first. But option 2 seems even better, assuming I can figure out what it means to read a tree into the index.

Comment: @rnrTom: See Somov's answer. (there's nothing "compressed" in a tar archive).

Comment: @mrTom `git archive --format zip --output "output.zip" master -0` will give you an uncompressed archive (-0 is the flag for uncompressed). http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive.

Comment: I concur with @mrTom, and I don't think whether the archive is compressed or uncompressed is the main issue. With SVN, I can `export` a 250 kB subdirectory directly from remote repository (which could otherwise be 200 MB in size, excluding revisions) - and I will only hit the network for 250 kB (or so) download transfer. With `git`, `archive` has to be enabled on server (so I can't try it) - `clone --depth 1` from server may still retrieve a repo of say 25 MB, where the `.git` subfolder alone takes 15MB. Therefore, I'd still say answer is "no".

Comment: @mrTom the answer is in fact **YES**
See the OP's answer - the command is `git checkout-index`

Comment: Here is a nice and simple way: `git archive -o latest.zip HEAD`

Comment: I've been using this question as the man-page for "git export" for years now, fyi.

Answer (score 2579, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to achieve this is with [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive). If you really need just the expanded tree you can do something like this.

```
git archive master | tar -x -C /somewhere/else
```

Most of the time that I need to 'export' something from git, I want a compressed archive in any case so I do something like this.

```
git archive master | bzip2 >source-tree.tar.bz2
```

ZIP archive:

```
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master
```

[`git help archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) for more details, it's quite flexible.

---

Be aware that even though the archive will not contain the .git directory, it will, however, contain other hidden git-specific files like .gitignore, .gitattributes, etc. If you don't want them in the archive, make sure you use the export-ignore attribute in a .gitattributes file and commit this before doing your archive. [Read more...](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/2010/02/excluding-files-from-git-archive.html)

---

Note: If you are interested in exporting the index, the command is

```
git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/destination/path/
```

(See [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/160719/413020) for more details)

---

Here's a real-world example using libchrony on Linux:

```bash
mkdir $HOME/dev
cd $HOME/dev
pushd /tmp
git clone https://gitlab.com/chrony/libchrony.git
cd libchrony
BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
git archive -o ../libchrony.zip --prefix="libchrony/" $BRANCH
popd
unzip /tmp/libchrony.zip
```

Those commands produce a zip file and extract it into `$HOME/dev/libchrony`. We can peek into the archive using:

```
$ unzip -v /tmp/libchrony
Archive:  /tmp/libchrony.zip
e0a3807f770b56f6b0e9833254baa7c4fc13564b
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 2023-07-20 09:37 00000000  libchrony/
      49  Defl:N       47   4% 2023-07-20 09:37 37c3f2e2  libchrony/.gitignore
   26530  Defl:N     9350  65% 2023-07-20 09:37 5622583e  libchrony/COPYING
     961  Defl:N      467  51% 2023-07-20 09:37 da9221e3  libchrony/Makefile
     475  Defl:N      304  36% 2023-07-20 09:37 cae27f70  libchrony/README.adoc
    3313  Defl:N     1119  66% 2023-07-20 09:37 37eb110f  libchrony/chrony.h
    7673  Defl:N     2261  71% 2023-07-20 09:37 5d455a52  libchrony/client.c
    6190  Defl:N     2093  66% 2023-07-20 09:37 7ea9d81b  libchrony/example-reports.c
   16348  Defl:N     3855  76% 2023-07-20 09:37 e82f5fe3  libchrony/message.c
    2946  Defl:N     1099  63% 2023-07-20 09:37 945ee82b  libchrony/message.h
--------          -------  ---                            -------
   64485            20595  68%                            10 files
```

Comment: ZIP archive: `git archive --format zip --output /full/path master`

Comment: Be aware that the archive will not contain the .git directory, but will contain other hidden git-specific files like .gitignore, .gitattributes, etc.  So if you don't want them, make sure you use the export-ignore attribute in a .gitattributes file and commit this before doing your archive.  See http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/2010/02/excluding-files-from-git-archive.html

Comment: To follow up on Streams' note: you can add a '--prefix=something/' string into the command to control the directory name that will be packed inside the zip. For example, if you use `git archive --format zip --output /path/to/file.zip --prefix=newdir/ master` the output will be called 'file.zip' but when you unpack it, the top level directory will be 'newdir'. (If you omit the --prefix attribute, the top level dir would be 'file'.)

Comment: and to follow up on @anotherAlan's note: the --prefix also works for tar archives -- and in either case, be sure to include the trailing /, if you're expecting a directory!

Comment: The easiest way: `git archive -o latest.zip HEAD` It create a Zip archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on the current branch. Note that the output format is inferred by the extension of the output file.

Comment: It does not support git submodules :(

Comment: You can get a tar by doing "--format=tar --output=foo.tar", you don't have to pipe it through tar.  In fact, according to git help archive, tar format is the default, so you don't even need to specify that.

Comment: @Liam: Yes, the default format is `tar` which is why you *can* pipe the output straight to `tar -x`.

Comment: For single files, it may be useful to pipe to stdout. e.g.: `git archive master some/file/name | tar -xO` (capital `O`, not zero).

Comment: @Charles Bailey: I wonder why you would choose this solution over clone + remove git-folders. Is there a downside to it?

Comment: @Яaffael1984: one reason to do this over the clone & remove git-folders method is if you want to export the git repo into/on top of an existing directory. `git clone` isn't happy about cloning into a non-empty directory.

Comment: Although this does work and is very simple, there is a big drawback which I have just come across.  This will export all the files from the tree and set their timestamp to the time of the last git commit, instead of each file retaining it's own timestamp, it will be overwritten with the last committed file's stamp.  This will then cause a problem for something like rsync if you were firing off your files to a remote server, all of the files will be transferred.

Comment: @jmoz: That's not a good use case for `git archive`. If you are interested in the timestamps of files in the working tree then a plain `tar`, `cp -pr` or local `rsync` is more appropriate.

Comment: `git archive --format zip --output "output.zip" master -0` will give you an uncompressed archive (-0 is the flag for uncompressed). http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

Comment: Nice, I added the zip option as an alias in `~/.gitconfig` `[alias] zip = archive --format zip --output`. Usage: `git zip ~/Desktop/app.zip master`

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this? `git archive -o ../{$GIT_DIR}.zip HEAD` I want to generate the zip file name dynamically based on the repo name or directory name.

Comment: The `--remote` option lets you create an archive without needing to clone it first.

Comment: Is there a way to archive only one folder of the project?

Comment: Note that .tar = no compression (less overhead) .tar.gz or bz2 means smaller files, but huge CPU usage.

Comment: "master" put me off. You really meant the name of the folder to export right? I replaced that with a dot.

Comment: Note that `git archive` is not a solution of you're using `git-lfs`.

Comment: git archive does not pick up files that are not committed.  I was trying to use it to make a backup of all of the files including files I was editing and it was not picking up the latest (edited) files.  This is as designed I'm sure.  I now need to find a way to get a list of every file in the HEAD and use cpio to copy the files so I pick up the files being edited. The command I need is git ls-tree -r master --name-only | cpio -pdmv /some/dest

Comment: As of today in most repost probably you would replace `master` with `main`

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to mess with the timestamps of unchanged files too, which can cause unnecessary rebuilds if you attempt to build...

Answer (score 348):

I found out what option 2 means. From a repository, you can do:

```
git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/destination/path/
```

The slash at the end of the path is important, otherwise it will result in the files being in /destination with a prefix of 'path'.

Since in a normal situation the index contains the contents of the repository, there is nothing special to do to "read the desired tree into the index". It's already there.

The `-a` flag is required to check out all files in the index (I'm not sure what it means to omit this flag in this situation, since it doesn't do what I want). The `-f` flag forces overwriting any existing files in the output, which this command doesn't normally do.

This appears to be the sort of "git export" I was looking for.

Comment: ...and DON'T FORGET THE SLASH AT THE END, or you won't have the desired effect ;)

Comment: Isn't the index just a name for the "staging" area? How's it that the tree is already there? I thought you can only add stuff manually to it with `git add`

Comment: The `git add` command changes content in the index, so whatever `git status` shows as "to be committed" is the *differences* between HEAD and the contents of the index.

Comment: seems that this is equivalent to `git archive HEAD`

Comment: @conny: read your comment, forgot about it and ran the command without a trailing slash. tip: follow conny's advice -.-

Comment: I like to remove other [cruft][1] too. For instance, I remove the `.gitignore` file as well, since it probably won't be relevant to any future maintainers of the software.

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruft

Comment: And apparently I didn't get the syntax correct in my comment above for linking to the term cruft on wikipedia. Sorry!

Comment: +1 to conny's advice.  Also, don't try to create '~/dest/', as this creates a directory called '~' in your working directory, rather than what you really wanted.  Guess what happens when you mindlessly type rm -rf ~

Comment: The reason for the '-a' flag is covered in the man page for git-checkout-index. It argues that git-checkout-index will frequently be accepting arguments, and sometimes no arguments means don't do anything. If you run `man git-checkout-index` and search for "Intuitive is not the goal here." you'll see the bit I'm talking about.

Comment: This method won't accept the tag or any other reference to the revision. Admittedly, the need to specify the tag was more important for CVS, as somebody else could have changed the remote repository. Another caveat is that the above method would export the files from the index. That is, if something is staged to be committed, it will be exported.

Comment: @KyleHeironimus - your warning about using '~/dest/` is true iff you use quotes around your prefix path which tells the shell not to perform tilde expansion. A dir called `~` (not `'~'` !) will be created in your working dir. There is nothing special about `git checkout-index` in this regard: The same is true of `mkdir '~/dest'` (*don't do that!*). Yet another good reason to avoid file names that need quoting (e.g. that have a space in them) :-)

Comment: I have not seen others mention that if the directory /destination/path/ does not already exist, you need to create it, as git will not do that for you and will silently do nothing unless it finds it.

Comment: @MattWallis: Using this approach in Windows with "Git Bash" as included in client available at git-scm.com tilde expansion doesn't work, though bash is using tilde as part of prompt. That isn't related to using quotes around pathname.
at Rich: In this very same scenario any output folder was created on demand.

Comment: @takeshin It's not exactly the same as `git archive HEAD`: `git checkout-index ...` copies all files _from the index_, while `archive` archives the files _from the local repository_. They'll coincidentally do the same if the index is empty.

Comment: Will `git checkout-index` try to re-use existing files similarly to what a normal `checkout` does (e.g. avoiding copying files with expected timestamp and size)?

Comment: For those wondering [what the index is](//git-scm.com/docs/git-add): The `.git/index` file _“holds a snapshot of the content of the working tree ... taken as the contents of the next commit. ... You must use the add command to add any new or modified files to the index.”_ One entry in it basically [consists](//git-scm.com/docs/index-format) of filename, checksum and some flags.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: the files do not have the correct timestamps.

Answer (score 272):

`git archive` also works with remote repository.

```
git archive --format=tar \
--remote=ssh://remote_server/remote_repository master | tar -xf -
```

To export particular path inside the repo add as many paths as you wish as last argument to git, e.g.:

```
git archive --format=tar \
--remote=ssh://remote_server/remote_repository master path1/ path2/ | tar -xv
```

Comment: This one is the option I like best. It has the additional benefit that it also works on bare repositories.

Comment: Am improved version is:

`git archive --format=tar --prefix=PROJECT_NAME/ --remote=USER@SERVER:PROJECT_NAME.git master | tar -xf -`

(ensures your archive is in a folder)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work on github for me. So i wrote a small wrapper in zsh: https://gist.github.com/1895274

Comment: this worked for me +1.  How do I specify a target foler based on this example?

Comment: Managed to answer my own question export to a specified directory

`git archive --format=tar --remote=ssh://remote_server/remote_repository master | (cd /path/to/dir/ && tar -xf -)`

Comment: **Note**: server must enable this feature.

Comment: if you're used to svn export http://repository.com/etc, this is the closest option.

Comment: I tried : `git archive --format=zip --output foo.zip --remote=https://github.com/xxx.git master`
And got fatal: Operation not supported by protocol.
Unexpected end of command stream.

Comment: @andyf only git and smart http protocol support it. If simple http on server, then it does not make it.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11258694/520567

Comment: @andyf GitHub has its own way: `curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/VENDOR/PROJECT/tarball | tar xzf -` per [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link)

Comment: @bishop GitHub supports (but doesn't advertise) the git protocol too. Just replace https:// with git:// in the URL.

Comment: @NeilMayhew It doesn't work for me, I get `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`. Tried on two different servers with jQuery github repo.

Comment: To compress it over the wire you can also use `git archive --format=tar.gz \
--remote=ssh://remote_server/remote_repository master path1/ path2/ | tar -xzv`

Answer (score 79):

[image]

#### A special case answer if the repository is hosted on GitHub.

Just use `svn export`.

As far as I know Github does not allow `archive --remote`. Although GitHub is [svn compatible](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support) and they do have all git repos `svn` accessible so you could just use `svn export` like you normally would with a few adjustments to your GitHub url.

For example to export an entire repository, notice how `trunk` in the URL replaces `master` (or whatever the [project's HEAD branch is set to](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/)):

```
svn export https://github.com/username/repo-name/trunk/
```

And you can export a single file or even a certain path or folder:

```
svn export https://github.com/username/repo-name/trunk/src/lib/folder
```

#### Example with [jQuery JavaScript Library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)

The `HEAD` branch or **master** branch will be available using `trunk`:

```
svn ls https://github.com/jquery/jquery/trunk
```

The non-`HEAD` **branches** will be accessible under `/branches/`:

```
svn ls https://github.com/jquery/jquery/branches/2.1-stable
```

All **tags** under `/tags/` in the same fashion:

```
svn ls https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tags/2.1.3
```

Comment: `git archive` works fine with GitHub, as long as you use the git protocol, Just replace `https://` with `git://` in the URL. I don't know why GitHub doesn't advertise this hidden feature.

Comment: @NeilMayhew It doesn't work for me, I get `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`. Tried on two different servers with jQuery github repo.

Comment: You're right. I'd forgotten that I was using `git config url.<base>.insteadOf` to cache the remote repository. I was therefore using a `file://` URL in reality. I doubt that `git archive` could ever work with `git://` URLs since it needs to be able to run `git-upload-archive` at the remote end. It should be possible using the `ssh` protocol, except that github doesn't allow it (`Invalid command: 'git-upload-archive'`).

Comment: Any way to use a local server tool behaving like github if I want to do it on internally hosted git repositories ?

Comment: upvoted -- it's completely bizarre that Git doesn't have this feature and we have to resort to svn

Comment: I wonder how to use `svn export` with 2FA or with API token on github.

Comment: Another option for fetching from GitHub is to use the REST API, see this Python script: https://gist.github.com/LewisGaul/65aa7d4ff5a20abb1c8ea02cd0948486

Comment: does it work with gitlab ?

Comment: When I tried to open `https://github.com/username/repo-name/trunk/` on any repository, github said "404 not found".  Are you sure this is still offered by github?

Answer (score 45):

From the [Git Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html):

Using git-checkout-index to "export an entire tree"

The prefix ability basically makes it trivial to use git-checkout-index as an "export as tree" function. Just read the desired tree into the index, and do:

`$ git checkout-index --prefix=git-export-dir/ -a`

Comment: I think the confusion is the phrase "read the desired tree into the index".

Comment: If you want to export directory foo in branch bar, then this would be
`git read-tree bar:foo`
And then
`git checkout-index --prefix=export_dir/ -a` after that maybe you should do `git update-index master`

Comment: @JohnWeldon Does it require you to clone the repo first? If so, then I wouldn't accept it, since the whole point of "svn export" of a subdirectory is  to directly get a copy of that subdirectory; if someone has a 1GB Git repo and all I want is a 10kB subdirectory, it's insane to require me to clone the whole thing.

Comment: Also I'd echo @davetron5000 with the comment "read the desired tree into the index" which I have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 40):

I've written a simple wrapper around `git-checkout-index` that you can use like this:

```
git export ~/the/destination/dir
```

If the destination directory already exists, you'll need to add `-f` or `--force`.

Installation is simple; just drop the script somewhere in your `PATH`, and make sure it's executable.

[The github repository for `git-export`](http://github.com/dasch/git-export/tree/master)

Comment: This wrapper is not platform-agnostic; it relies on /bin/sh. So if you're on Windows, this solution _probably_ won't work for you.

Comment: Uhh, this script is 57 lines of documentation, whitespace, setup, argument parsing, and only one line which actually does something...

Answer (score 36):

It appears that this is less of an issue with Git than SVN.  Git only puts a .git folder in the repository root, whereas SVN puts a .svn folder in every subdirectory.  So "svn export" avoids recursive command-line magic, whereas with Git recursion is not necessary.

Comment: As of SVN 1.7, there is also only one .svn folder: https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#single-db

Comment: This won't get rid of any additional build files that svn export deletes. So this is definitely not the answer.

Answer (score 30):

The equivalent of

```
svn export . otherpath
```

inside an existing repo is

```
git archive branchname | (cd otherpath; tar x)
```

The equivalent of

```
svn export url otherpath
```

is

```
git archive --remote=url branchname | (cd otherpath; tar x)
```

Comment: thanks, this was what I was missing... also, to check the timestamps of the export (they will not be preserved as on the files), use `git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (tar -t -v --full-time -f -)` ... However, archiving with timestamps is not exactly trivial, so I posted an [example below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export/24760614#24760614).

Comment: You can use the C option for tar instead of the subshell, like this:  `git archive branchname | tar xC otherpath`

Comment: Heads up that the `C` option to tar is GNU Tar only.

Answer (score 25):

If you're not excluding files with `.gitattributes` `export-ignore` then try `git checkout`

```
mkdir /path/to/checkout/
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/checkout/ checkout -f -q
```

> -f
>   When checking out paths from the index, do not fail upon unmerged
>   entries; instead, unmerged entries are ignored.

and

> -q
>   Avoid verbose

Additionally you can get any Branch or Tag or from a specific Commit Revision like in SVN just adding the SHA1 (SHA1 in Git is the equivalent to the Revision Number in SVN)

```
mkdir /path/to/checkout/
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/checkout/ checkout 2ef2e1f2de5f3d4f5e87df7d8 -f -q -- ./
```

The `/path/to/checkout/` must be empty, Git will not delete any file, but will overwrite files with the same name without any warning

UPDATE:
To avoid the beheaded problem or to leave intact the working repository when using checkout for export with tags, branches or SHA1, you need to add `-- ./` at the end

The double dash `--` tells git that everything after the dashes are paths or files, and also in this case tells `git checkout` to not change the `HEAD`

Examples:

This command will get just the libs directory and also the `readme.txt` file from that exactly commit

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/checkout/ checkout fef2e1f2de5f3d4f5e87df7d8 -f -q -- ./libs ./docs/readme.txt
```

This will create(overwrite) `my_file_2_behind_HEAD.txt` two commits behind the head `HEAD^2`

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/checkout/ checkout HEAD^2 -f -q -- ./my_file_2_behind_HEAD.txt
```

To get the export of another branch

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/checkout/ checkout myotherbranch -f -q -- ./
```

Notice that `./` is relative to the root of the repository

Comment: Actually, among numerous others and upvotes, this worked best for me, without any compressions, working fine with bare repositories (gitolite).

Comment: Notice that the SHA1 checkout will create a "behead" problem in the repository

Comment: actualy @ITGabs, this does not download ".git" folder. So the downloaded folder is not a git repository, so it is not technically "beheaded"

Comment: @FabioMarreco The behead issue is on the repository not in the exported/downloaded files, I am updating the answer for more details

Comment: This worked great for me. But at first I got "Not a git repository" error messages. Then I found that "/path/to/repo/" had to point to the .git folder. So this worked:

    --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git

Comment: What if I want to export an earlier commit? First, checkout to earlier commit with `git checkout <sha1>`, then your command `git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/ --work-tree=/path/to/checkout/ checkout -f -q`?

Comment: The command worked well. The only drawback observed is that it is not possible to run `git checkout ...` in parallel. Running in parallel gives: `fatal: Unable to create '.../index.lock': File exists.`. Have to use `git clone --branch ... /path/to/repo/.git /path/to/checkout` instead: it works when running in parallel.

Answer (score 22):

I use git-submodules extensively.
This one works for me:

```
rsync -a ./FROM/ ./TO --exclude='.*'
```

Comment: Wouldn't that miss files whose names start with a dot, such as `.htaccess`?

Comment: A good solution, I would change --exclude='.*' to --exclude='.git*'

Comment: --exclude-vcs if you were going to take this tact

Comment: Can ./FROM/ be a remote repo?

Comment: I would replace --exclude='.*' to --exclude='.git*'

Comment: As an FYI, my copy of `rsync` lists the argument as `--cvs-exclude`. Additionally, it still copies over `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore`

Answer (score 22):

I have hit this page frequently when looking for a way to export a git repository. My answer to this question considers three properties that svn export has by design compared to git, since svn follows a centralized repository approach:

- It minimizes the traffic to a remote repository location by not exporting all revisions
- It does not include meta information in the export directory
- Exporting a certain branch using svn is accomplished by specifying the appropriate path

  ```
    git clone --depth 1 --branch main git://git.somewhere destination_path
    rm -rf destination_path/.git
  ```

When building a certain release it is useful to clone a stable branch as for example `--branch stable` or `--branch release/0.9`.

Comment: This does not work if the destination exists and is non-empty.

Comment: **The One True Answer:** *it arises from the depths.* The `git archive | tar` approach is inapplicable to POSIX-incompatible shell environments (e.g., AppVeyor's CMD- or PowerShell-based CI), which is non-ideal. The `git checkout` approach modifies the index of the main working tree, which is awful. The `git checkout-index` approach requires the index of the main working tree to be modified beforehand, which is even awful-er. The traditional `git clone` approach clones the entirety of the repository's history before deleting that history, which is wasteful. This is the only sane solution left.

Comment: To export locally, note that the absolute path of the Git working tree to be cloned from should be prefixed by the `file://` protocol (e.g., `git clone --depth 1 --branch v3.14.15 file:///home/me/src_repo trg_repo`). Failing to do so will emit `"warning: --depth is ignored in local clones; use file:// instead."` and perform a standard rather than shallow clone, defeating the entire purpose of this answer. *Salud!*

Comment: `master` --> `main` as of today in most repos

Comment: For the celebrations to the tenth anniversary of this answer I renamed  the branch name.

Answer (score 16):

This will copy all contents, minus the .dot files. I use this to export git cloned projects into my web app's git repo without the .git stuff.

> cp -R ./path-to-git-repo /path/to/destination/

Plain old bash works just great :)

Comment: Why not just push to remote? Even simpler than bash.

Comment: what about files that are part of web applications and its name starts with dot? :) think about .htaccess

Comment: Sometimes you also want to ignore what's in `.gitignore`, this won't.

Answer (score 14):

As simple as clone then delete the .git folder:

```
git clone url_of_your_repo path_to_export && rm -rf path_to_export/.git
```

Comment: Honestly - this answer, which is also #1 in the question - is what you're going to be doing 99% of the time. Most of these answers are crazy overcomplicated.

Comment: −1. First, this way is already mentioned in the question as one that doesn't satisfy the question author. Second, in this way the whole history will be downloaded, which can be much larger than the useful part. Please at least include `--depth 1`. Third, even if this answer is improved, it adds nothing to [the Lars Schillingmann's answer](/a/8963061).

Answer (score 12):

For GitHub users, the `git archive --remote` method won't work directly, as [the export URL is ephemeral](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link).  You must ask GitHub for the URL, then download that URL.  `curl` makes that easy:

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/VENDOR/PROJECT/tarball | tar xzf -
```

This will give you the exported code in a local directory.  Example:

```
$ curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/jpic/bashworks/tarball | tar xzf -
$ ls jpic-bashworks-34f4441/
break  conf  docs  hack  LICENSE  mlog  module  mpd  mtests  os  README.rst  remote  todo  vcs  vps  wepcrack
```

---

**Edit**
If you want the code put into a specific, *existing* directory (rather than the random one from github):

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/VENDOR/PROJECT/tarball | \
tar xzC /path/you/want --strip 1
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163769/4221299) is a clean and neat command to archive your code without any git inclusion in the archive and is good to pass around without worrying about any git commit history.

```
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master
```

Comment: This is great, just need to remove gitignore after and it is done and ready to share.

Comment: Removing .gitgnore etc. is mentioned in accepted answer comments: use .gitattributes file, see https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/excluding-files-from-git-archive/

Answer (score 10):

I just want to point out that in the case that you are

1. exporting a sub folder of the repository (that's how I used to use SVN export feature)
2. are OK with copying everything from that folder to the deployment destination
3. and since you already have a copy of the entire repository in place.

Then you can just use `cp foo [destination]` instead of the mentioned `git-archive master foo | -x -C [destination]`.

Answer (score 9):

You can archive a remote repo at any commit as zip file.

```
git archive --format=zip --output=archive.zip --remote=USERNAME@HOSTNAME:PROJECTNAME.git HASHOFGITCOMMIT
```

Answer (score 8):

My preference would actually be to have a **dist** target in your Makefile (or other build system) that exports a distributable archive of your code (.tar.bz2, .zip, .jar, or whatever is appropriate).  If you happen to be using GNU autotools or Perl's MakeMaker systems, I think this exists for you automatically.  If not, I highly recommend adding it.

ETA (2012-09-06): Wow, harsh downvotes.  I still believe it is better to build your distributions with your build tools rather than your source code control tool.  I believe in building artifacts with build tools.  In my current job, our main product is built with an ant target.  We are in the midst of switching source code control systems, and the presence of this ant target means one less hassle in migration.

Comment: The project I had in mind isn't a code project; it happens to be more along the lines of a web site project.

Comment: Doesn't address the question.

Comment: Yeah, such an answer may not fit everybody's needs, but the downvotes are bizarre.  It _is_ a totally valid answer, and indeed, in many scenarios, the only correct answer. It makes the very valid point that thinking about this issue as a "vc tool issue" is often going down the wrong path entirely.

Answer (score 8):

If you want something that works with submodules this might be worth a go.

Note:

- MASTER_DIR = a checkout with your submodules checked out also
- DEST_DIR = where this export will end up
- If you have rsync, I think you'd be able to do the same thing with even less ball ache.

Assumptions:

- You need to run this from the parent directory of MASTER_DIR ( i.e from MASTER_DIR cd .. )
- DEST_DIR is assumed to have been created. This is pretty easy to modify to include the creation of a DEST_DIR if you wanted to

> cd MASTER_DIR && tar -zcvf ../DEST_DIR/export.tar.gz --exclude='.git*'
>   . && cd ../DEST_DIR/ && tar xvfz export.tar.gz && rm export.tar.gz

Answer (score 8):

As I understand the question, it it more about downloading just certain state from the server, without history, and without data of other branches, rather than extracting a state from a local repository (as many anwsers here do).

That can be done like this:

```
git clone -b someBranch --depth 1 --single-branch git://somewhere.com/repo.git \
&& rm -rf repo/.git/
```

- `--single-branch` is available since Git 1.7.10 (April 2012).
- `--depth` is (was?) [reportedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708231/git-shallow-clone-clone-depth-misses-remote-branches) faulty, but for the case of an export, the mentioned issues should not matter.

Comment: Note: I just noticed there are 2 pages of anwsers, I only looked at one before posting. There is one similar anwser with only `--depth`, which implies `--single-branch` unless `--no-single-branch` is given, which means this has probably the same effect. Not sure though, some expert may confirm?

Answer (score 7):

Bash-implementation of git-export.

I have segmented the .empty file creation and removal processes on their own function, with the purpose of re-using them in the 'git-archive' implementation (will be posted later on).

I have also added the '.gitattributes' file to the process in order to remove un-wanted files from the target export folder.
Included verbosity to the process while making the 'git-export' function more efficient.

EMPTY_FILE=".empty";

```
function create_empty () {
## Processing path (target-dir):
    TRG_PATH="${1}";
## Component(s):
    EXCLUDE_DIR=".git";
echo -en "\nAdding '${EMPTY_FILE}' files to empty folder(s): ...";
    find ${TRG_PATH} -not -path "*/${EXCLUDE_DIR}/*" -type d -empty -exec touch {}/${EMPTY_FILE} \;
#echo "done.";
## Purging SRC/TRG_DIRs variable(s):
    unset TRG_PATH EMPTY_FILE EXCLUDE_DIR;
    return 0;
  }

declare -a GIT_EXCLUDE;
function load_exclude () {
    SRC_PATH="${1}";
    ITEMS=0; while read LINE; do
#      echo -e "Line [${ITEMS}]: '${LINE%%\ *}'";
      GIT_EXCLUDE[((ITEMS++))]=${LINE%%\ *};
    done < ${SRC_PATH}/.gitattributes;
    GIT_EXCLUDE[${ITEMS}]="${EMPTY_FILE}";
## Purging variable(s):
    unset SRC_PATH ITEMS;
    return 0;
  }

function purge_empty () {
## Processing path (Source/Target-dir):
    SRC_PATH="${1}";
    TRG_PATH="${2}";
echo -e "\nPurging Git-Specific component(s): ... ";
    find ${SRC_PATH} -type f -name ${EMPTY_FILE} -exec /bin/rm '{}' \;
    for xRULE in ${GIT_EXCLUDE[@]}; do
echo -en "    '${TRG_PATH}/{${xRULE}}' files ... ";
      find ${TRG_PATH} -type f -name "${xRULE}" -exec /bin/rm -rf '{}' \;
echo "done.'";
    done;
echo -e "done.\n"
## Purging SRC/TRG_PATHs variable(s):
    unset SRC_PATH; unset TRG_PATH;
    return 0;
  }

function git-export () {
    TRG_DIR="${1}"; SRC_DIR="${2}";
    if [ -z "${SRC_DIR}" ]; then SRC_DIR="${PWD}"; fi
    load_exclude "${SRC_DIR}";
## Dynamically added '.empty' files to the Git-Structure:
    create_empty "${SRC_DIR}";
    GIT_COMMIT="Including '${EMPTY_FILE}' files into Git-Index container."; #echo -e "\n${GIT_COMMIT}";
    git add .; git commit --quiet --all --verbose --message "${GIT_COMMIT}";
    if [ "${?}" -eq 0 ]; then echo " done."; fi
    /bin/rm -rf ${TRG_DIR} && mkdir -p "${TRG_DIR}";
echo -en "\nChecking-Out Index component(s): ... ";
    git checkout-index --prefix=${TRG_DIR}/ -q -f -a
## Reset: --mixed = reset HEAD and index:
    if [ "${?}" -eq 0 ]; then
echo "done."; echo -en "Resetting HEAD and Index: ... ";
        git reset --soft HEAD^;
        if [ "${?}" -eq 0 ]; then
echo "done.";
## Purging Git-specific components and '.empty' files from Target-Dir:
            purge_empty "${SRC_DIR}" "${TRG_DIR}"
          else echo "failed.";
        fi
## Archiving exported-content:
echo -en "Archiving Checked-Out component(s): ... ";
        if [ -f "${TRG_DIR}.tgz" ]; then /bin/rm ${TRG_DIR}.tgz; fi
        cd ${TRG_DIR} && tar -czf ${TRG_DIR}.tgz ./; cd ${SRC_DIR}
echo "done.";
## Listing *.tgz file attributes:
## Warning: Un-TAR this file to a specific directory:
        ls -al ${TRG_DIR}.tgz
      else echo "failed.";
    fi
## Purgin all references to Un-Staged File(s):
   git reset HEAD;
## Purging SRC/TRG_DIRs variable(s):
    unset SRC_DIR; unset TRG_DIR;
    echo "";
    return 0;
  }
```

> Output:
>
> $ git-export /tmp/rel-1.0.0
>
> Adding '.empty' files to empty folder(s): ... done.
>
> Checking-Out Index component(s): ... done.
>
> Resetting HEAD and Index: ... done.
>
> Purging Git-Specific component(s): ...
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.buildpath}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.project}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.gitignore}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.git}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.gitattributes}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{*.mno}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{*~}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.*~}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{*.swp}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{*.swo}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.DS_Store}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.settings}' files ... done.'
>
> '/tmp/rel-1.0.0/{.empty}' files ... done.'
>
> done.
>
> Archiving Checked-Out component(s): ... done.
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 admin  wheel  25445901  3 Nov 12:57 /tmp/rel-1.0.0.tgz
>
> I have now incorporated the 'git archive' functionality into a single process that makes use of 'create_empty' function and other features.

```
function git-archive () {
    PREFIX="${1}"; ## sudo mkdir -p ${PREFIX}
    REPO_PATH="`echo "${2}"|awk -F: '{print $1}'`";
    RELEASE="`echo "${2}"|awk -F: '{print $2}'`";
    USER_PATH="${PWD}";
echo "$PREFIX $REPO_PATH $RELEASE $USER_PATH";
## Dynamically added '.empty' files to the Git-Structure:
    cd "${REPO_PATH}"; populate_empty .; echo -en "\n";
#    git archive --prefix=git-1.4.0/ -o git-1.4.0.tar.gz v1.4.0
# e.g.: git-archive /var/www/htdocs /repos/domain.name/website:rel-1.0.0 --explode
    OUTPUT_FILE="${USER_PATH}/${RELEASE}.tar.gz";
    git archive --verbose --prefix=${PREFIX}/ -o ${OUTPUT_FILE} ${RELEASE}
    cd "${USER_PATH}";
    if [[ "${3}" =~ [--explode] ]]; then
      if [ -d "./${RELEASE}" ]; then /bin/rm -rf "./${RELEASE}"; fi
      mkdir -p ./${RELEASE}; tar -xzf "${OUTPUT_FILE}" -C ./${RELEASE}
    fi
## Purging SRC/TRG_DIRs variable(s):
    unset PREFIX REPO_PATH RELEASE USER_PATH OUTPUT_FILE;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Usage: git-archive [/var/www/htdocs] /repos/web.domain/website:rel-1.0.0

Answer (score 7):

a git export to a zip archive while adding a prefix (e.g. directory name):

```
git archive master --prefix=directoryWithinZip/  --format=zip -o out.zip
```

Answer (score 6):

This will copy the files in a range of commits (C to G) to a tar file. Note: this will only get the files commited. Not the entire repository. Slightly modified from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541300/export-only-modified-and-added-files-with-folder-structure-in-git)

Example Commit History

A --> B --> **C --> D --> E --> F --> G** --> H --> I

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT C~..G | xargs tar -rf myTarFile.tar
```

[git-diff-tree Manual Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541300/export-only-modified-and-added-files-with-folder-structure-in-git)

-r --> recurse into sub-trees

--no-commit-id --> git diff-tree outputs a line with the commit ID when applicable. This flag suppressed the commit ID output.

--name-only --> Show only names of changed files.

--diff-filter=ACMRT --> Select only these files. [See here for full list of files](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree)

C..G --> Files in this range of commits

C~ --> Include files from Commit C. Not just files since Commit C.

| xargs tar -rf myTarFile --> outputs to tar

Answer (score 6):

By far the easiest way i've seen to do it (and works on windows as well) is `git bundle`:

`git bundle create /some/bundle/path.bundle --all`

See this answer for more details: [How can I copy my git repository from my windows machine to a linux machine via usb drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522089/how-can-i-copy-my-git-repository-from-my-windows-machine-to-a-linux-machine-via/28522093#28522093)

Comment: `git bundle` includes the `.git` folder, which is what the OP does not want; `git archive` seems the more appropriate way

Comment: Where is documentation on the `--all` switch?

Comment: @GarretWilson it's weird.  --all here isn't an option to git bundle create, even though it sure looks like it.  --all is a legal value to pass as git-rev-list, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list.

Answer (score 4):

I needed this for a deploy script and I couldn't use any of the above mentioned approaches. Instead I figured out a different solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -eq 2 ] || echo "USAGE $0 REPOSITORY DESTINATION" && exit 1
REPOSITORY=$1
DESTINATION=$2
TMPNAME="/tmp/$(basename $REPOSITORY).$$"
git clone $REPOSITORY $TMPNAME
rm -rf $TMPNAME/.git
mkdir -p $DESTINATION
cp -r $TMPNAME/* $DESTINATION
rm -rf $TMPNAME
```

Comment: What was the issue with either a read-tree/checkout-index or archive solution? As far as I can tell you've done the equivalent of something like `mkdir -p "$2" && git --git-dir="$1" archive HEAD | tar -x -C "$2"` but somewhat longer winded.

Comment: I couldn't get read-tree to work from a remote repository, and the archive solution doesn't work with github.

Comment: Yes with archive get a Invalid command: 'git-upload-archive '... error and i dont have core.gitProxy config option and the
  GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable set

Answer (score 4):

Doing it the easy way, this is a function for .bash_profile, it directly unzips the archive on current location, configure first your usual [url:path]. NOTE: With this function you avoid the clone operation, it gets directly from the remote repo.

```
gitss() {
    URL=[url:path]

    TMPFILE="`/bin/tempfile`"
    if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
        echo -e "Use: gitss repo [tree/commit]\n"
        return
    fi
    if [ "$2" = "" ]; then
        TREEISH="HEAD"
    else
        TREEISH="$2"
    fi
    echo "Getting $1/$TREEISH..."
    git archive --format=zip --remote=$URL/$1 $TREEISH > $TMPFILE && unzip $TMPFILE && echo -e "\nDone\n"
    rm $TMPFILE
}
```

Alias for .gitconfig, same configuration required (TAKE CARE executing the command inside .git projects, it ALWAYS jumps to the base dir previously [as said here](http://www.kerneltrap.com/mailarchive/git/2008/12/3/4301934/thread), until this is fixed I personally prefer the function

```
ss = !env GIT_TMPFILE="`/bin/tempfile`" sh -c 'git archive --format=zip --remote=[url:path]/$1 $2 \ > $GIT_TMPFILE && unzip $GIT_TMPFILE && rm $GIT_TMPFILE' -
```

Answer (score 4):

I have another solution that works fine if you have a local copy of the repository on the machine where you would like to create the export. In this case move to this repository directory, and enter this command:

`GIT_WORK_TREE=outputdirectory git checkout -f`

This is particularly useful if you manage a website with a git repository and would like to checkout a clean version in `/var/www/`. In this case, add thiscommand in a `.git/hooks/post-receive` script (`hooks/post-receive` on a bare repository, which is more suitable in this situation)

Answer (score 3):

I think [@Aredridel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416271/277826)'s post was closest, but there's a bit more to that - so I will add this here; the thing is, in `svn`, if you're in a subfolder of a repo, and you do:

```
/media/disk/repo_svn/subdir$ svn export . /media/disk2/repo_svn_B/subdir
```

then `svn` will export all files that are under revision control (they could have also freshly Added; or Modified status) - and if you have other "junk" in that directory (and I'm not counting `.svn` subfolders here, but visible stuff like `.o` files), it will *not* be exported; only those files registered by the SVN repo will be exported. For me, one nice thing is that this export also includes files with local changes that have *not* been committed yet; and another nice thing is that the timestamps of the exported files are the same as the original ones. Or, as `svn help export` puts it:

> 2. Exports a clean directory tree from the working copy specified by
>      PATH1, at revision REV if it is given, otherwise at WORKING, into
>      PATH2. ... If REV is not specified, all local
>      changes will be preserved.  Files not under version control will
>      not be copied.

To realize that `git` will not preserve the timestamps, compare the output of these commands (in a subfolder of a `git` repo of your choice):

```
/media/disk/git_svn/subdir$ ls -la .
```

... and:

```
/media/disk/git_svn/subdir$ git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (tar -t -v --full-time -f -)
```

... and I, in any case, notice that `git archive` causes all the timestamps of the archived file to be the same! `git help archive` says:

> git archive behaves differently when given a tree ID versus when given a commit ID or tag ID. In the first case the
>   current time is used as the modification time of each file in the archive. In the latter case the commit time as recorded
>   in the referenced commit object is used instead.

... but apparently both cases set the "modification time of *each* file"; thereby *not* preserving the actual timestamps of those files!

So, in order to also preserve the timestamps, here is a `bash` script, which is actually a "one-liner", albeit somewhat complicated - so below it is posted in multiple lines:

```bash
/media/disk/git_svn/subdir$ git archive --format=tar master | (tar tf -) | (\
  DEST="/media/diskC/tmp/subdirB"; \
  CWD="$PWD"; \
  while read line; do \
    DN=$(dirname "$line"); BN=$(basename "$line"); \
    SRD="$CWD"; TGD="$DEST"; \
    if [ "$DN" != "." ]; then \
      SRD="$SRD/$DN" ; TGD="$TGD/$DN" ; \
      if [ ! -d "$TGD" ] ; then \
        CMD="mkdir \"$TGD\"; touch -r \"$SRD\" \"$TGD\""; \
        echo "$CMD"; \
        eval "$CMD"; \
      fi; \
    fi; \
    CMD="cp -a \"$SRD/$BN\" \"$TGD/\""; \
    echo "$CMD"; \
    eval "$CMD"; \
    done \
)
```

Note that it is assumed that you're exporting the contents in "current" directory (above, `/media/disk/git_svn/subdir`) - and the destination you're exporting into is somewhat inconveniently placed, but it is in `DEST` environment variable. Note that with this script; you must create the `DEST` directory manually yourself, before running the above script.

After the script is ran, you should be able to compare:

```
ls -la /media/disk/git_svn/subdir
ls -la /media/diskC/tmp/subdirB   # DEST
```

... and hopefully see the same timestamps (for those files that were under version control).

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you need submodules as well, this should do the trick: https://github.com/meitar/git-archive-all.sh/wiki

Comment: Actually, looks like it has a few small issues so it might not be ready for prime time yet.

Answer (score 2):

The option 1 sounds not too efficient. What if there is no space in the client to do a clone and *then* remove the `.git` folder?

Today I found myself trying to do this, where the client is a Raspberry Pi with almost no space left. Furthermore, I also want to exclude some heavy folder from the repository.

Option 2 and others answers here do not help in this scenario. Neither `git archive` (because require to commit a `.gitattributes` file, and I don't want to save this exclusion in the repository).

Here I share my solution, similar to option 3, but without the need of `git clone`:

```
tmp=`mktemp`
git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD > $tmp
rsync -avz --files-from=$tmp --exclude='fonts/*' . raspberry:
```

Changing the `rsync` line for an equivalent line for compress will also work as a `git archive` but with a sort of exclusion option (as is asked [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=466912)).

Answer (score 1):

i have the following utility function in my .bashrc file: it creates an archive of the current branch in a git repository.

```
function garchive()
{
  if [[ "x$1" == "x-h" || "x$1" == "x" ]]; then
    cat <<EOF
Usage: garchive <archive-name>
create zip archive of the current branch into <archive-name>
EOF
  else
    local oname=$1
    set -x
    local bname=$(git branch | grep -F "*" | sed -e 's#^*##')
    git archive --format zip --output ${oname} ${bname}
    set +x
  fi
}
```