# Cloning a single path of a bare git repository

Tags: git, clone, fetch, post-commit, pull

I am trying to add a post-commit hook to a bare repository, such that whenever a commit is made the changed files are automatically installed in a (hardcoded) directory.

Is there a way to fetch a single file from the repository?

git-clone does not appear to allow for specifying a path, and any other commands that I found (git-fetch, git-pull) seem to require an existing local git repository to work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the answers in: [How to do a "git export"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

In particular, `git checkout-index` will probably do the job for you:

```
git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/destination/path/
```

Don't forget the trailing slash or this command won't do exactly what you want.

Comment: git checkout-index does not work with a bare repository ("fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree").
However, the link that you posted also suggests git-archive, which works fine: ("git archive master TESTFILE | tar -x -C /my/destination") Thanks!

Comment: Ah, interesting, I guess a bare repository doesn't have an index to read from. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract a single file from any revision in a bare repository with `git show`, using the syntax `git show <rev>:<filename>`, e.g.:

```
 $ ls
 branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  packed-refs  refs
 $ git show master:COPYING > /tmp/COPYING
 $ head -5 /tmp/COPYING
                     GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
                        Version 3, 29 June 2007

  Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. 
  Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies
```

There are [a couple of examples in the git-show(1) man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html#_examples).  I hope that's of some use.