# How do I acquire a "cleansed" Git repository?

Tags: git

I can't seem to find the answer to this seemingly simple question, anywhere:  How do you acquire a clean copy of a code repository once you "release" it?  For instance, say I'm at a place in my Git repository where I want to release a copy. How do I copy it without all the Gitiness?  I don't want any hidden Git directories, etc.  I want a clean deliverable product.  Ideas? I'm working with RoR, btw.

Best

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want [git archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.6.5.6/git-archive.html), e.g.

```
git archive --format=tar -o /path/to/archive.tar master
```

Note that the above gets you a whole tree. If you want, can pare it down to only specific directories, including going down multiple "levels":

```
git archive --format=tar -o /path/to/archive.tar master somedir/ another/dir/
```

Answer (score 4):

In your git directory, there's really only one directory that is "gitty," and that is .git.

Here's what I propose, you check out your release branch and copy it elsewhere, except for the .git folder. This packs your working directory into a tarball:

```
$tar --exclude .git -cjf release.tar.bz2 *
```

Comment: What about `.gitignore` files? Aren't those also "gitty"? This would include those in the tarball. I'm not sure if `git archive` will exclude them by default, but it might. If it doesn't, it could be configured to do so with the `export-ignore` attribute.