# How to clone only a branch's working directory from a git repository without .git folder

Tags: git

Is there any git command that allow me to "clone" from a git repository but only the working directory of specified branch is cloned without .git folder that has all logs and version history?

There are few reasons to work with multiple working directory on single .git repo. Reason 1: I have few branch in a git, I want to work and see these branch at the same time without git checkout that may override files in branches. Reason 2: I want to make a software release of particular branch but don't want to disturb the branch that I am working.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the behavior of `svn export` ? If so, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866358/git-checkout-only-files-without-repository might help you.

Comment: Manojlds: There are few reasons to work with multiple working directory on single .git repo.  Reason 1: I have few branch in a git, I want to work and see these branch at the same time without git checkout that may override files in branches.  Reason 2: I want to make a software release of particular branch but don't want to disturb the branch that I am working.

Comment: Why don't you make another clone ( or just copy the existing repo) and checkout another branch in that? I have said the same in my answer, you can comment there. I have update your question with the above comment.

Comment: An extra clone will require push/pull to sync between repositories.  More over, a clone will have extra .git folder to store history/logs.

Comment: Clones on a single filesystem will use hardlinks for the blob files, which means that you'll use little extra disk space or time in cloning.

Comment: There's also some way to have a work tree separated from its repository directory, but I can't seem to find the script at the moment.

Comment: Novelocrat: I come across this: "git --work-tree=new-working --git-dir=<project>/.git checkout <working-branch> ."  It works in normal git repository, but it need some work on project that has submodules

Answer (score 3):

As per OP's latest comment:

Why don't you make another clone ( or just copy the existing repo) and checkout another branch in that?

Git-Archive can help you:

Sample from the docs:

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)
```

You can also use the `--remote` flag to get it from a remote archive.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html

Answer (score 3):

On Linux (or Windows too, if you install [a commandline `tar` client](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm)):

```
git archive <commitish> | tar -x -C /path/to/folder
```

Basically, this tells git to build an archive (tarball) of the source tree at revision `<commitish>` and then pipes it through tar which extracts it into a folder.

Unfortunately, `git` doesn't currently support this directly.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is downvote.  Perhaps someone don't like my question at all.

Comment: Matthew: git archive might help but I need extra untar operation to extract the source.  This is inconvenient if I use git in Windows.

Comment: @Chau Chee Yang: Totally agree with you, unfortunately this is the only solution as `git` doesn't have an operation analogous to `svn export` built into it.