# git checkout-index only for committed files

Tags: git

I am currently exporting a git repository using:

`git checkout-index -f --prefix=$TARGET_PATH/ $GIT_REPO_PATH/*`

Actual behavior: The export happens on all files that are added to the index.

Desired behavior: Export all files that are not only added, but committed too.

I tried to use the `--stage`-option, but the stage is 0 for committed and uncommitted files (I have to say, I did not yet understand the stage numbers yet.

Any idea?

Comment: Because it creates an archive (obviously ;) ), and I just need a plain export.

Comment: So, what's wrong with `git archive HEAD | tar x -C"$TARGET_PATH"`?

Comment: Well, this compresses and then uncompresses the repository files. Practically it works, but it takes time and creates load. Isn't there a common way, how to do this?

Comment: `tar` (without `-j` or `-z` options) does not compress. Copying takes time as well, I doubt there will be a noticeable overhead when using tar.

Comment: That's true. But using tar in between seems to be somehow senseless to me. But okay, if there is no direct way, I obviously have to cope with it. I will have to check if there is noticeable overhead.

Comment: I'm adding this as an answer, since it seems to solve your problem.

Comment: see also/not-quite-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2866358/151502

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that in one command, you have to load the files from a commits tree into an index first. Luckily, you don't have to use the normal index you work with:

```
$ export GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/tmp-index
$ git read-tree HEAD && git checkout-index --prefix=/path/dir/ -f -a
$ rm "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple, naïve solution to this problem is to use `git archive`.
It will extract a tree from git history and write it to standard output.
Piping trough tar allows you to write the files to a particular directory on disk.

```
# HEAD to use latest committed version
git archive HEAD | tar x -C"/path/to/dir"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `git --work-tree=<path/to/wherever> checkout <HEAD/branch/hash> -- .` does what you want. It will create a copy of (every file as it exists in the specified commit) in (the path specified by `--work-tree`).

Comment: This is the best answer, but you need to create the directory by yourself, otherwise you get this error: `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`