# git download, not clone fetch etc

Tags: git, github

I want a command line tool to download a Github repo without creating a local git repo.

One idea is a download tool to download Github zips from a url like

https://github.com/lukeholder/fuel-website/zipball/master

I'm on Windows 7 and don't want to have to install curl or wget and use only a only native tool.

It would be preferable to not download a zip, but just somehow clone the repo and not have the local git repo ever created.

Do you have any ideas without using git? In effect it would be a `git clone` and `del .git` directory

Comment: Just curious, why?  If you just clone and delete the .git, it's just done.

Comment: @JakubNarębski `fatal: depth 0 is not a positive number` Did this option change? (Using v2.7.4 on Mac OS X)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you were willing to still use git (just not create a repository) you could do it with `git archive` as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export).

Answer (score 3):

Immediately above the main directory (***to the right***) for the folder/files being viewed is a tab with a ***URL*** and a **"Download" button** to pull all the files.

If you ***DO NOT*** see those options then you must click the directory link above the viewing area (i.e. ***some name > some folder > some other folder***) to essentially back out of the directory until you see the option to **"Download"** and that is the entire compressed file to be downloaded.