# How can I "check out" my git repo's code into another directory?

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I want to create a file tree of a branch of my repo in an arbitrary place. Is this possible to do? Kind of like `svn export`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to `svn export` that I'm aware of is using git archive, then extracting the result. Like so:

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix=SomeName HEAD
```

Then extract the tar.