# GIT: Checkout to a "Really" Specific Folder

Tags: git, git-checkout

I want to export, checkout, or whatever you call it from the index, HEAD, or any other commit, to a specific folder, how is that possible? Similar questions have already been asked:

[GIT: Checkout to a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479960/git-checkout-to-a-specific-folder)

[Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export/160719)

But the problem with the proposed solution is that they preserve the relative path. So for example, if I use the mentioned method to check out the file nbapp/editblog.php to the folder temp, the file would be checked out in temp/nbapp/editblog.php!

Is there anyway to checkout to 'temp' directly?

Also, another important thing is to be able to check the HEAD or any other commit. The checkout-index (which allows using the --prefix option to checkout to a specific folder, while normal checkout doesn't allow) checks out only the index. What if I want to check out a file from a certain commit to a certain folder?
A similar question has alread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git cat-file blob revision:path > path/where/to/save/file`

Comment: It's worth noting that `cat-file` won't perform and `autocrlf` or other work-tree specific mangling.

Answer (score 1):

With `git archive`, you can include the path elements that you don't want to replicate in the specification of the treeish. E.g.

```
git archive --prefix=temp/ HEAD:nbapp editblog.php | tar x
```

creates `temp/editblog.php`, whereas

```
git archive --prefix=temp/ HEAD nbapp/editblog.php | tar x
```

creates `temp/nbapp/editblog.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--work-tree`

This forces you to also use `--git-dir` to point to your .git directory.
`--git-dir=.git` assumes that your are in your git folder. You can of course invoke this command from anywhere else, by adjusting this folder.

And then specify a `<tree>` instead of a commit. This removes the leading pathes.

```
git  --git-dir=.git  --work-tree=/folder/into/which/to/export/  restore  --source=HEAD:path/in/your/repo  .
```

Using `:path/in/your/repo` should use the index.

If you only want one file, then name the file instead of using a "." at the end.

If you want part of the folder structure (for the sub-path) to be created in the dest folder

```
git  --git-dir=.git  --work-tree=/folder/into/which/to/export/  restore  --source=HEAD:path/in/  your/repo
```

Still only exports `path/in/your/repo`.
But creates the directory `/folder/into/which/to/export/your/repo`.