# How to export a subdir from git branch

Tags: git

I'm looking for the equivalent of `svn export` in `git`. But I actually want to export only one subdir. My structure looks like this:

```
/db
/html
/tools
...
```

I want to export only the `/html` dir in the repo, from given branch (let's say `master`) to some directory on the fs but without the internal `.git` dirs and omitting the files under `.gitignore` files. Ideally something like:

```
cd my_repo_dir
git export master/html/* /var/www/my_website_docroot
```

Can I do this and how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479960/git-checkout-to-a-specific-folder

Comment: Thanks man, I will mark to close as duplicate!

Comment: There's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export.  Also, as an option, you could always just export the entire repo, then delete everything you don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout-index -f --prefix=/path/to/folder/ html/*
```

Comment: This says "not in cache" for each subdir in `html/*`

Comment: It's a low level command, so it doesn't have a recursive option to deal with subdirectories. You would have to find all files in all subdirectories yourself and pass it to the command, e.g. `find html/ -type f | git checkout-index -f --prefix=/path/to/folder/ --stdin`

Comment: @Veseliq, that would happen if git does not recognize the html dir..add and commit all the stuff then try