# git first branch remove initial local branch and clone master and bench branch in distinct folders

Tags: git, azure-devops

I created a Visual Studio .net core 3.1 project with visual studio 2019 and Azure Devops.
I cloned the ripo master in :

d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution
I created a [bench] branch

Now, I would like to have 2 local folders :

d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution\master

d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution\bench

so I can create two web application endpoints.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT: Checkout to a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479960/git-checkout-to-a-specific-folder)

Comment: Hi Laurent,
not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

For a git repository, it's possible to checkout branches into separate folders. In your case, `d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution` is the main working tree with `master` checked out. You can checkout `bench` into another working tree,

```
git worktree add <path_to_bench_worktree> bench
```

`path_to_bench_worktree` could be any valid path, for example `d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution_bench`.

The 2 working trees share the same git folder, `d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution\.git`. You can modify files and commit changes in both working trees, one for `master` and the other for `bench`. You can create more working trees when necessary.

When you think a working tree is not needed any more, you can remove it,

```
# in the main working tree
git worktree remove <path_to_bench_worktree>
```

You can also remove `path_to_bench_worktree` first and then in the main working tree,

```
git worktree prune
```

Comment: I think I would have :

d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution\master

d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution\bench

d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution\prod

master is the latest version

bench the pre prod version

prod the current production version

So, first I need to move d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution to d:\myprojects\myclient\mysolution\master

Comment: With TFS, when I want to merge code from one branch to another, I first get the latest version of the target code and then I merge the source code into the cilble.
The system indicates conflicts.
We solve them, we compile and if it works, we check in the target branch.
I can't seem to do the same with GIT