# Xcode and Git: fatal: Not a git repository after removing .git folder in project

Tags: xcode, git

I deleted the .git folder from my project as it had a large size and I did not need it. Now I get the problem when trying to rename one of my files `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

So i went into the organizer and removed the project from the repositories tab. Save and reopen, but when the project opens a new repository is created, and the same message again when I try to rename

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754152/git-how-to-remove-git-tracking-from-a-project. Make sure to Quit Xcode after you removed the project from the repositories ab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode probably has some Git metadata elsewhere and that probably is making it confused when it doesn't find the .git folder (where all the repository commit data was).

Things to try: `Product -> Clean` and `Organizer -> Projects -> Delete derived data`.

If that doesn't work, here's a more extreme workaround.

- Create a new project on Xcode from scratch, unticking the *Create repository* box in Xcode. Then move all your files from your broken project to the new one.

---

*Edit*: As per OP's comment, make sure you actually deleted the `.git` folder (if that is what you actually want to do). This is a hidden folder and it doesn't normally show in Finder. You can list and delete it from the Terminal.

Comment: I did as you mentioned - then one additional step, cause even thought I had removed the .git from the project folder in the organizer - the .git folder was still in there (hidden). So i removed it. Working now