# Copy a version control folder and remove the git connection

Tags: git

I copied a folder which is linked to a git repository control but the copied folder is also  linked to the git repository how can I stop linking it to be just a normal folder in my pc ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git - how to remove git tracking from a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754152/git-how-to-remove-git-tracking-from-a-project)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the .git directory from parent folder

```
rm -rf .git/
```

Or, you could even use

```
find . | grep .git | xargs rm -rf
```