# deleting source control history from Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I am trying to remove all my source control stuff from my project and then setting it up new.
Since I have changed the project's name and deleted some files I committed before.

I tried the following:

1. Just committing my "new" application => results in XCode not being able to find the ViewControllers I wanted to "update".
2. Creating a new Branch and submitting this => basically the same error.
3. Disabling Source Control and Reenable it => no difference

Also, when I try to 'checkout' I am getting a `Reference 'refs/heads/master' not found (-9)` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just setup a new repo?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you explain what you mean by that? I created a new repo just for this on GitHub, but I figure the problem is my local Git

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754152/git-how-to-remove-git-tracking-from-a-project . This would remove all commit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
rm -fr .git
```

Comment: thanks, this allowed me to create a new working copy. But I am still getting the Reference error...