# Remove branch master git on C:/Users/Username

Tags: git

I do a mistake, I do "git init" at the opening of the console, when the path is on C:/Users/My Username. So now my entire disc C is the branch master while I wanted to do the git init on a file from my desktop.
So how to remove this branch in order to fix my problem do what i want ?
Thank's :)

Comment: Just delete the `.git` directory in whatever directory you ran the command in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove version tracking from a project cloned from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754152/how-do-i-remove-version-tracking-from-a-project-cloned-from-git)

Answer (score 0):

If you did the `git init` in `C:/Users/Username`, then why should your whole `C:` be in the repo? o_O

Everything Git-specific is in `.git` of the root directory of the repository. So if you did init a Git repo in `C:/Users/Username`, delete `C:/Users/Username/.git`. If you did init a Git repo in `C:`, delete `C:/.git`.

Answer (score 0):

How to Remove Git from the Project?
To remove Git from a project we can remove the .git folder using the Git command.

```
rm -rf .git*
```