# How do I remove Xamarin (Visual Studio for Mac) Source Control? I need to switch to a different server

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

I need to change my source control target from one server to another, and need to remove source control (and all history if possible) from my project.

What is the correct way to do this?  I tried the `Source Control.. Remove` command on both the project and solution, restarted, and inspected for hidden .Git files that could be present.  The system still behaves as if source control is still enabled.

What other things should I try when removing this from Source Control?

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf .git` should do it. Or just delete `.git/` hidden folder manually. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754152/how-do-i-remove-git-tracking-from-a-project) to a similar question.