# Remove Git Hub related files

Tags: github-for-windows

I am learning Git Hub. So I am a newbie.
Trying to remove git related files in project directory. I used this line:

```
rd .git /S/Q
```

However it gives me this error when I use VS Code:

> Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/q'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + rd /s /q .git
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

and when I use CMD - command promt it gives me this error:

```
.git\refs\remotes - The directory is not empty.
```

What is going on.
This is where I get my information about this:
[From stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754152/how-do-i-remove-git-tracking-from-a-project)
[From YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVL7R0eT8jw&list=PLJs8CRshSlRV-Raaafr7KmUNAk8qnkK-7&index=2&t=0s)

I am using Windows 10 btw.

EDIT:
I tried:

```
rd /S /Q .git
```

and I get error:

> Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/Q'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + rd /S /Q .git
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException

Tried:

```
rd /S/Q .git
```

Error:

> Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.git'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + rd /S/Q .git
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException

However I tried in command promt:

```
rd /S /Q .git
```

And I get :

```
.git\refs\remotes - The directory is not empty.
```

I try it second time right after that and it works...
So what am I missing here?

EDIT 2:

All of these comands work in command promt but only if I type them for the second time. Including the command - rd .git /S/Q.
The first time I get :

```
.git\refs\remotes - The directory is not empty.
```

and if I type it for the second time it works.
In VS Code it is not working no matter how many times I type them.

Comment: Doesn't the error message just say that the switches (i.e., `/S /Q`) need to go before the files / directories you want to delete? Try `rd /S /Q .git` (also note the space before each slash).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried it and the results are in the edit section of my question