# Remove all git files from a directory?

Tags: git

I have a folder under version control.  I want to make a copy of it to send around, but don't want to include all the .git directories and the files underneath it.

Is there a way to remove all the git files instead of manually deleting all of them?

Comment: You can write a little script to do this, but that would be operating system specific.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The .git folder is only stored in the root directory of the repo, not all the sub-directories like subversion. You should be able to just delete that one folder, unless you are using Submodules...then they will have one too.

Comment: Ah terrific, was thinking it was distributed among all subdirs like svn!

Comment: Why would you *delete* it? Use `git archive`; it's for this purpose, or even just tar up everything except the .git directory.

Comment: You may want to also delete your `.gitignore` file and such. I guess you could write a script to do that, but it might be simpler to just use git-archive and then manually delete them from the archived version.

Comment: [Here](http://www.gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/29/exporting-your-repository.html) you can find examples of how to use `git archive` which Jefromi mentions. There is also a link back to Stackoverflow question [160608](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export).

Comment: You are being unnecessarily clever. It's entirely possible to have a vendor directory with all sorts of other repos cloned into it. Git only stores a root `.git` but you can have repos everywhere, eg. `vendor/something/something/.git`.

Comment: Don't forget about the `.gitmodules` file and any corresponding submodules as well..

Comment: You can have a workspace folder that is linked to a given repo and the have a repo per app/service you have within your workspace, in this case you'll obviously have a `.git` folder per app/service. So your assumption that you could only have one `.git` at the root folder is completely wrong.

Answer (score 103):

**How to remove all `.git` directories under a folder in Linux.**

Run this find command, it will list all `.git` directories under the current folder:

```
find . -type d -name ".git" \
&& find . -name ".gitignore" \
&& find . -name ".gitmodules"
```

Prints:

```
./.git
./.gitmodules
./foobar/.git
./footbar2/.git
./footbar2/.gitignore
```

There should only be like 3 or 4 `.git` directories because git only has one .git folder for every project.  You can `rm -rf yourpath` each of the above by hand.

**If you feel like removing them all in one command and living dangerously:**

```
//Retrieve all the files named ".git" and pump them into 'rm -rf'
//WARNING if you don't understand why/how this command works, DO NOT run it!

( find . -type d -name ".git" \
  && find . -name ".gitignore" \
  && find . -name ".gitmodules" ) | xargs rm -rf

//WARNING, if you accidentally pipe a `.` or `/` or other wildcard
//into xargs rm -rf, then the next question you will have is: "why is
//the bash ls command not found?  Requiring an OS reinstall.
```

Comment: @Jay Taylor, do I type the backslashes or is that part of the command?

Comment: Yes- the trailing slashes are for readability.  In this form I suppose it qualifies as a "multi-line command".

Comment: Consider removing the `.repo` folder (at the top of the tree) when removing all Git-related folders (if doing Android development). http://source.android.com/source/developing.html

Comment: I would remove the `-type d` clause from the `.git` find statement, so the submodules .git files are also deleted.

Answer (score 25):

`cd` to the repository then

```
find . -name ".git*" -exec rm -R {} \;
```

Make sure not to accidentally pipe a single dot, slash, asterisk, or other regex wildcard into find, or else `rm` will happily delete it.

Comment: This is great but I get a notice after `find: ./.git: No such file or directory` it works though. Anyway to stop the notice from showing?

Comment: If you're sure about the outcome, you can add `2>/dev/null` by the end to get rid of the `find: ./.git: No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [git-archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html), for example:

```
git archive master | bzip2 > project.tar.bz2
```

Where `master` is the desired branch.

Comment: this takes 2h versus instantaneous `cp -r`

Comment: @gcb: `cp -r` doesn't deal with files and directories that are not part of the repository, which also includes ignored ones. However, if you are certain you don't need this and your processing/time is critical, sure, go ahead with `cp`.

Comment: To be fair, `git archive` has a drawback - It does not export submodules. One would need to `git submodule foreach --recursive git archive ...`. Extremely bad!

Comment: Refusing to include submodules is a feature, not a drawback.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone else stumbles onto this topic - here's a more "one size fits all" solution.

If you are using `.git` or `.svn`, you can use the `--exclude-vcs` option for tar. This will ignore many different files/folders required by different version control systems.

If you want to read more about it, check out:
http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/exclude.html

Answer (score 2):

With PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\path\to\folder -Filter ".git" -Recurse -Attributes "H" | Remove-Item -Force
```

More explanation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369640/6710876
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#parameters

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other source control systems like SVN or CVS, git stores all of its metadata in a *single* directory, rather than in every subdirectory of the project. So just delete `.git` from the root (or use a script like [git-export](http://www.ohloh.net/p/git-export)) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

**ls | xargs find 2>/dev/null | egrep /\.git$ | xargs rm -rf**

This command (and it is just one command) will recursively remove .git directories (and files) that are in a directory without deleting the top-level git repo, which is handy if you want to commit all of your files without managing any submodules.

**find 2>/dev/null | egrep /\.git$ | xargs rm -rf**

This command will do the same thing, but will also delete the .git folder from the top-level directory.

Answer (score 1):

sudo find -name .git -exec rm -fr {} ;