# Does git create files/folders in the project tree?

Tags: git

Does git create any files/folders (hidden?) in the project tree at all?

If so, is there a way to export all the raw files and not git related files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git creates a single `.git` directory in the root of the project. You can create additional git-specific files like `.gitignore` and `.gitmodules`, but by default only the `.git` directory will be present.

There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) to 'export' your project; simply deleting the `.git` directory is probably the simplest.

Comment: I'd argue that `git archive` is a better approach to suggest as simplest, since there's no way you can possibly accidentally screw yourself up, and you don't have to make extra copies like you presumably would to be able to delete the `.git` directory.