# How to get a copy of a directory from another git branch in a transparent way?

Tags: git, packaging, git-branch, pypi

How can a directory be copied from a git branch to another *without git tracking the files*?

My goal is to have different branches for a project and be able to import part of each branch to a single directory for packaging ?  Each branch contains code for a specific version of Python, but the package must contain the code for *all* the Python versions, so the code from all version-specific branches must be copied into the master branch before packaging.

Here is an example:

- The git-controlled, master-branch directory contains:

  ```
  uncertainties/
  ```
- I want to import the version of `uncertainties/` contained in the `python-pre-2.5` branch, so that the final directories are:

  ```
  uncertainties/  # Should not be touched
  uncertainties-py23/  # Imported from the python-pre-2.5 branch
  ```
- A crucial point is that I do not want `git status` to report any change (if there was no change in the first place).  In other words, the directory import process should be invisible to git.

By using `git checkout python-pre-2.5 -- uncertainties` and various combinations of renames (`mv` and `git mv`), I did not succeed in satisfying this last "git transparency" requirement.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From master,

```
git archive python-pre-2.5 uncertanties > uncertanties-py23.tar
mkdir uncertainties-py23
tar xf uncertanties-py23.tar --strip-components=1 -C uncertanties-py23
```

And then add `uncertanties-*/` or similar to your .gitignore.

Comment: The `git archive` command is good to know: thanks!  I actually did `tar -C /tmp -xf uncertainties-py23.tar; mv /tmp/uncertainties uncertainties-py23` (no `mkdir` or `--strip-components=1` necessary).

Comment: PS: `git archive --output uncertainties-py23.tar …` is also an alternative that does not depend on how the shell handles file clobbering (`>` in sh, `>!` is zsh,…).

Answer (score 2):

Just put `uncertainties-py23/` in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks!  This almost works:  `git status` reports changed files.  However, `git commit -a` does not find any file to be committed anything.  How can I have `git status` not report changed files?

Comment: The files from `uncertainties/` are marked as being modified and staged for commit, but git refers to their imported `python-pre-2.5` version; at the same time, `git status` also reports the modification of the original (master branch) files, with unstaged changes.  `git diff` reports changes (and `git commit -a` does not want to commit anything!).

Comment: Ah, I think the problem is that `git checkout` makes git think it is on that branch now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export