# copy a git repository without revisions (without .git and .gitingore) from a remote server

Tags: git

How to copy a git repository directly form remote server without .git directory and .gitignore files?. In advance from a tag name or branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exact "svn export" equivalent command for git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538668/exact-svn-export-equivalent-command-for-git)

Answer (score 14):

You can use the command

```
git archive branchname
```

to archive files from a named tree. I.e. you can pass the output to `tar` to pack the files or filter files like `.gitignore` (`.git` will not be exported):

```
git archive branchname | tar -x -C c:\git-my-branch
```

Checkout out `git help archive` for more details.

The equivalent of `svn export . otherpath` inside an existing repo is

```
git archive branchname | (cd otherpath; tar x)
```

The equivalent of `svn export url otherpath` is

```
git archive --remote=url branchname | (cd otherpath; tar x)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for something like last command (git archive --remote=url branchname | (cd otherpath; tar x)) But this is not working. For example following is not working
git archive --remote=git@github.com:gihanshp/WordPress-Widget-Boilerplate.git master| cd /tmp/

Comment: Have you tried the 'git archive branchname | (cd otherpath; tar x)'?

Comment: I am trying to directly copy from the remote server

Comment: make a local copy first with 'git clone' and them use abovementioned commands.

Comment: The reason is this. I want to get a copy of my project to the production server. The revision history is huge (about 1G). So I don't wan't to download that garbage in to production server and trying to speed up the process. Thanks anyway for your quick help.

Comment: @gihan, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6538833/372643): use `--depth 1`.

Comment: I tried "git archive develop --output=./develop.tar".  Then when I do "tar tvf develop.tar" it only gives me abou 12 random files, not the entire develolp branch (which is huge).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but my way is using scp recursively, ignoring hidden files:

```
scp -r {git_directory}/* {target_directory}
```

For example:

```
scp -r /local/yourProjectGit/* user@machine:/home/user/dist

scp -r /local/yourProjectGit/* /local/youtProyect/dist
```