# How to check out a version with tig or command line?

Tags: git

I have a git repository on my machine, and at the moment it is only for this machine and myself to trace different versions of development.

I have been using basically git console commands, and `tig` to visualize different commits.

I just want to know what is the simplest way to check out a version, to another working folder on my machine...

Answer (score 1):

»[…] check out a version, to another working folder« suggests that you are looking for the `git clone` command:

```
git clone /path/to/your/repo /new/repo
cd /new/repo
git checkout <branch/tag/sha1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git checkout-index`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-checkout-index) if you want to export only the files.

1. If your working directory is "dirty", stash away your changes with `git stash`
2. Checkout the version you want with `git checkout <version>`
3. Export to desired directory with `git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/destination/path/`
4. Go back to where you were with `git checkout HEAD@{1}`
5. Pop your changes back off with `git stash pop`

If your working directory is clean you can omit steps 1 and 5.

Here is [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) with some more details.