# Possible to git clone into a new project?

Tags: git

I have created a framework that I would like to base all of my projects off of.

It would be nice if I could git clone it into a new project with out all of the git info.

Is my only solution to delete the .git folder after I clone?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking for [git submodules](http://help.github.com/submodules/), which allow your solutions to include projects hosted by another repository. So, basically, you should just add a submodule (referring to the repository your framework is hosted by) to the repository containing your project based off your framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `.git` then you have to either clone and delete and use the `git archive` command's remote option to directly get the contents of the repo ( while piping it and untar it).

If you are more flexible, `git submodules` is meant for this purpose, but it will be equivalent to cloning a repo, but the submodules information will be tracked in the root repo and anyone cloning the repo will be able to get the submodules.