# How can I copy the tree of a particular commit to a non-working folder?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a local Git repository and all I want to do is copy all of the files from a particular revision to a folder outside of the working directory. I was assuming that it would just be a single command.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't for the life of me work it out.

Thanks,
LJ

Comment: You can use [git archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/).

Comment: Thanks Charles, that was very quick and very easy. Much appreciated. I don't use SO very much but if I can work out how to I'll mark your response as the answer!

Comment: @CharlesBailey. Charles I can't seem to mark a comment as the correct answer, so if you add an answer I'll happily mark it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=../other/path git checkout -f <hash> -- *
```

Comment: Thanks manojlds, but I think I'll stick to git archive as I'm more likely to remember that!