# git - copy all files from one branch to arbitrary folder in current branch, unstaged

Tags: git

Lets say I have the following two branches and the local branch is 'mybranch'

```
master
master\file.txt
master\directory\file2.txt
...

mybranch
mybranch\otherfile.txt
```

I'd like to create a new directory, call it 'test'.  I'd like to put ALL of the contents of master into `mybranch\test`.  I don't want those files and directories staged, just copied.

I've tried `git checkout mybranch --` with various combinations of wildcards, slashes, dots, and I just can't get it to work.

So in this example, my end result would be

```
mybranch
mybranch\otherfile.txt
mybranch\test\file.txt
mybranch\test\directory\file2.txt
```

Can this be done without switching branches?

Comment: Looks like you could do this with `git archive`, see first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export).

Comment: @tcovo - could you add as answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export), you can use `git archive` to retrieve the contents of a commit, and then extract the archive to the desired location:

```
git archive master | tar -x -C test
```