# After 'git clone <some_repo>' inside <my_repo>, I want to make <some_repo> part of <my_repo>

Tags: git

I have my personal git repo name `myrepo`. I have fetched `somerepo` using `git clone` and now I want to make it an integral-part of `myrepo`. I am thinking of doing it as following.

1. Inside `myrepo` tree, `git clone <somerepo>`.
2. Remove all git-related files and directories from `somerepo` such as `.git` `.gitignore` etc.
3. Add all files in fetched `somerepo` and commit.

Is there any command which clones only 'raw' data of a git-repo (ignore git-related files)? Better still, is there a command (or may be more than one) which can do these three steps.

I have read about `git submodule` a bit. Can `submodule` be used? Assume that I don't have any interest in future-modification in `somerepo`.

Comment: you can use a submodule, or you can do a subtree merge … both will preserve full history of the "foreign" repository (which is generally what you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not understand the question, because it sounds like you've already answered it.

After cloning, just `rm -fr` the .git directory. There's only one .git directory per repository, so it's easy to remove it. (Not like subversion where you have .svn in each directory.)

You said, "assume I don't have any future interest," so there's no need to remove .gitignore files. But if you really wanted to, that's also pretty easy:

```
$ find <path_to_some_repo> -name '.gitignore' -exec rm {} \;
```

Finally, `git add <path_to_some_repo>` and you're done.

If that's not what you're looking for, then please explain your requirements more precisely.

> Is there any command which clones only 'raw' data of a git-repo (ignore git-related files)?

Not literally, because "clone" in git means to fetch all of the refs and objects in the repository. There *is* `git checkout-index` which is kind of similar to "svn export", but you still have to have a copy of the repository in order to do that.

See: [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: I was looking for a single command inside git without going through all of this. Something like `git pull-and-merge-in-tree some-repo` ..

Answer (score 0):

You can add the second repository as a remote:

```
git remote add some_repo git@server:some-repo
```

Issue `git pull some_repo` or `git fetch some_repo` + manual merge afterwards.

A [subtree merge](http://help.github.com/subtree-merge/) might be appropiate as well.

Comment: Preferably you'd do a subtree merge, to move all files into a subtree of the repository

Comment: @Fermaref If I do `git clone <my-repo>` on some other machine after doing your steps. Will I fetch some-repo automatically?

Comment: Feel free to propose an edit/detail the commands in a comment I'll approve/add it myself.

Comment: @Dilawar: After you merged some-repo into my-repo and pushed it back to the original remote, it (and its history) will be part of my-repo, and with the next pull everybody will get it.

Comment: @Femaref in your command `git remote ... git@server:some-repo`, server is server of my-repo or some-repo?

Comment: it's the path to some-repo, the operation is done in my-repo. Make sure you have no working tree changes though.