# Create Working Tree from Bare Git Repo

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do a “git export” (like “svn export”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

I have a bare git repository that I created using "git clone --bare". This is a repository where I push updates to, and does not contain a working tree of the source files.

I wanted to know if it is possible to create a working tree from this bare repository? I know I could do a "git clone" on the bare repository, but I would like to create copy of the working tree without the .git directory, just the source files essentially. The copy of the working tree does not need to be under source control, it is just essentially the source files from the bare git repository.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export

Comment: A very popular question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export

Comment: I felt there was a better way to do this than what I was doing and your reference was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!