# git archive fatal: Operation not supported by protocol

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-archive

I'm trying to checkout part of remote git repository. As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export), with help of command

```
git archive --format=zip --remote=http://path_to_repository
```

But I'm getting error message:

```
fatal: Operation not supported by protocol.
Unexpected end of command stream
```

Git is not supporting this operation with http protocol? Thats a problem of hosting environment or git itself? Any directions would help, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

`git archive` can work with a server with git protocol support (i.e. git server, [smart-http](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) and ssh server).

In your case, either your git is too old, or the server is dumb http server (normal http server, without "[smart](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP)" git support). You need to clone the repository and archive from there.

Comment: Smart HTTP is used by our git server... What else could it be?

Comment: according to protocol description smart http is excluded as well: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt

Answer (score 10):

you can't use git achieve with http! only git protocol.  i.e.

```
git archive --format=zip --remote=git://path_to_repository
```

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up this claim?

Comment: I seems not working with git protocol in all cases. For example, there is a repo https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata. I can clone it as git://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata.git thus the URL is correct. However if I try "git archive --remote=git://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata.git 4.0.0 eng.traineddata" it says "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly". Do you have a clue what is the cause?

Comment: Found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659758/git-archive-remote-end-hung-up. This does not work at all with GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

> Git is not supporting this operation with http protocol?

It should, with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024... 12 years later), [batch 12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc7ee2e5e16f0d1e710ef8fab3db59ab11f2bbe7): "[`git archive --remote=<remote>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa50e7a8a08741c798fa72c1177e78966d0cd553/Documentation/git-archive.txt#L98)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#Documentation/git-archive.txt---remoteltrepogt))</sup> learned to talk over the smart http (aka stateless) transport.

See [commit 176cd68](https://github.com/git/git/commit/176cd68634c4641cc45030dc7f287be47d1809d1), [commit 35d26e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35d26e79f8d8c030269a198d07de939bd3f5ea08), [commit 24f275a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24f275ab33cd06f399a87a8384443e74da5f3545), [commit 5c85836](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c858368966f71ffeba78e2fa9aaecec02050f3c), [commit 23b7d59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23b7d59a82ce39c0e08a4052de3be9ffbccd99b9), [commit 4a61faf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a61faf75d684eb31c23521bc0e3c3cac5fd1553) (21 Jan 2024) by [Jiang Xin (`jiangxin`)](https://github.com/jiangxin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fa50e7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa50e7a8a08741c798fa72c1177e78966d0cd553), 30 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`remote-curl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23b7d59a82ce39c0e08a4052de3be9ffbccd99b9): supports git-upload-archive service
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jiang Xin</sup>

> Add new service (git-upload-archive) support in remote-curl, so we can support remote archive over HTTP/HTTPS protocols.
> Differences between [`git-upload-archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/23b7d59a82ce39c0e08a4052de3be9ffbccd99b9/Documentation/git-upload-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-archive))</sup> and other services:
>
> 1. The [`git-archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/23b7d59a82ce39c0e08a4052de3be9ffbccd99b9/Documentation/git-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> program does not expect to see protocol version and capabilities when connecting to remote-helper, so do not send them in remote-curl for the `git-upload-archive` service.
> 2. We need to detect protocol version by calling `discover_refs()`.
>    Fallback to use the [`git-upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/23b7d59a82ce39c0e08a4052de3be9ffbccd99b9/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup> service (which, like `git-upload-archive`, is a read-only operation) to discover protocol version.

And:

> ### [`transport-helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c858368966f71ffeba78e2fa9aaecec02050f3c): protocol v2 supports upload-archive
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jiang Xin</sup>

> We used to support only [`git-upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5c858368966f71ffeba78e2fa9aaecec02050f3c/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup> service for protocol v2.
> In order to support remote archive over HTTP/HTTPS protocols, add new service support for [`git-upload-archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5c858368966f71ffeba78e2fa9aaecec02050f3c/Documentation/git-upload-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-archive))</sup> in protocol v2.

And: