# Git downloading directory from a remote repository

Tags: git

I want to download a sub tree content from remote Git repository as a zip archive without versioning information, I don’t want to clone a local repo or even a do a fetch… I know that github (and gitblit...) have their own support for this but I am looking for a generic git command, it looks like the git archive should be a perfect fit but I was not able to run it successfully with the -–remote flag… I also didn’t find working examples with the --remote flag.

git archive --format=zip --remote=http://myserver:8080/r/RepoTest.git -o myfile.zip HEAD

I get:

fatal: Operation not supported by protocol.
Unexpected end of command stream

Thanks!

BTW: I am using Git Bash from Windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258599/git-archive-fatal-operation-not-supported-by-protocol

Comment: In regards to duplicates... I am using SCM Manager which is a repository with smart http according to them https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scmmanager/smart$20http%7Csort:relevance/scmmanager/JMQB-KCWI44/h7YR1N6RPpEJ

Comment: BTW the suggestion from the above (I have seen them) – either don’t work or require clone first, a thing I want to avoid.