# Git-archive remote end hung up

Tags: git, github

I was trying to checkout single file from Github. After following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository)  thread I tried

```
git archive --format=tar --remote=ssh://git@github.com:user/project.git HEAD:README.md
```

I get the following error

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Edit:
I tried getting file from raw by getting head from `git ls-remote url`. Then using this head I got the file using wget. But I would like to know how to do it using git commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer from github docs on [Can I archive a repository?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160330193528/https://help.github.com/articles/can-i-archive-a-repository/)

> GitHub does not provide archiving.
>
> If you want to consider a workaround, you can emulate archives locally by fully cloning the repository to a local machine. This will make you responsible for your own backups.