# Git Setup on My UBUNTU envrionment

Tags: git, github

I have got some questions about GIT. The scenario is the following:

I have an ubuntu server with my development environment in the folder /var/www/ and I would like to use GIT in conbination with Github. The Joomla component I am devloping is in the folder /var/www/subfolder/ Normally I am programming in the components/mycomponent diretory by accessing it with my laptop and I would like to keep it that way. But I would like t get some track on the changes i have made.

How should I setup GIT as I read everywhere you should not setup GIT in the /var/www/ folder?

Hope to get some good advise how I should set this up.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't deploy your project with the `.git` directory to a production setup. But if you use your server for development and testing purposes only, it should be okay to do it this way. At least, I don't see a reason why it's such a bad idea, if the setup works for you. If you want, you can configure the HTTP server to deny access to `.git/` so that nobody can access it.

However, the preferred way would be to develop the module on your local machine and deploy it to your server using scripts, build automation tools or manually. Usually you would create some kind of artifact which a user can install, e.g. a ZIP file. Your build script or tool should generate such an artifact and this is (automatically) deployed to the server for further integration testing.

But since you want to keep your development model, just clone the repo on the server, as mentioned above.

**References:**

- [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: I am working alone so this is why I have an UBUNTU server and programming directly in the /var/www/ folder. I can do small changes and see the results directly if needed. Otherwise I have to pull and commit changes everytime. Or does it look more work then I can imagine at this moment? (NOTE: I am new to GIT and GITHUB so i want the best solution and if possible do it once :))

Answer (score 0):

as long as you

- set your docroot to a folder within the git repo

or

- configure your webserver not to deliver the .git folder

or

- only access the webserver locally for development purposes

i do not see a problem with serving directly from a git clone in `/var/www/`

Comment: Thanks! I will checkout ho to do this as I have never worked with GIT and GITHUB. But there are probably many tutorials :)