# How to checkout old Symfony 2.0.23 version with Vendors

Tags: php, symfony, github, symfony-2.0, vendors

I'm trying to update the old server, which runs Symfony 2.0.X and vendors to the latest version 2.0.23 with Vendors.
Unfortunatelly I can't find anywhere I can find Symfony 2.0.23 with vendors. On official site:
http://symfony.com/download

And on GitHub:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/releases/tag/v2.0.23

None of them have a version with Vendors. The download is only about 180 KiB. While version with Vendors is About 8 MiB.

Also, can I use Symfony 2.0.23 and vendors folder from Symfony 2.3.1 ? Is that compatible.

Also, maybe anyone heard about "Export" option for Git and Windows 8, or at least Ubuntu, so I could "Export" vendors from our "old Symfony version with Vendors"?

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 2):

What about downloading the corresponding `deps` and `deps.lock` files from the [Symfony Standard Edition v2.0.23](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/v2.0.23) and run `bin/vendors` locally?

Then export the project using `git archive -o latest.zip HEAD` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)). This will keep off all those `.git` directories. You may need to touch your `.gitignore` and/or `.gitattributes` file to be sure that the vendors aren't excluded on archiving.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are very unlikely that you can run Symfony 2.0.23 with the vendor directory from 2.3.1

If you need to use Symfony 2.0.23 then its probably easiest to use composer.

Otherwise, I know they keep an archive of previous versions on the Symfony website but I'm pretty sure they do not include the vendor directory.