# Is it possible to remove git history from the vendor directory when using composer in a PHP project

Tags: git, composer-php

I am using composer in a PHP project. I've noticed that my vendor folder is particularly large. Upon inspecting the folders inside I've noticed that some packages are very large (~30Mb) however the actual files which have been checked out amount to no more than a couple of Kilobytes; the .git folder is massive!

I'm working on some extremely restrictive hosts so need to use as little disk space as possible.

Is it possible to have composer import JUST the actual package files, and not maintain the git history? Or, does composer require the git history to understand what version of the package it has installed etc? I'd assume that it can 'remember' this based on the composer.lock file.

I've seen a number of pages which suggest that it's possible to do what I'm asking using vanilla Git ([link](http://breckyunits.net/git-clone-without-history.html) | [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)), but can composer be configured to do this?

Hope the question is clear!

Answer (score 2):

Don't copy the `.git` folders to the web host. This should never really be done unless you have a use case (like it is the key component in your deployment scheme).

The second method would be to import the distribution ZIP files instead of cloning the repository (command line option `--prefer-dist`), but this would only work out of the box for Github hosted libraries, because Github offers ZIP files for almost everything at a known location, and Composer makes use of it. For your own hosted git repositories, you'd manually or with the help of Satis create ZIP files of your tagged versions, and add these to your libraries `composer.json`, and then to your main software instead.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. I guess i wasn't sure if I could run a command on deployment to find and remove .git folders (I run the composer install command on the server automatically). I just wasn't sure if composer relied on the individual vendor .git folders to know where it's at when updating etc (if that makes any sense?).My hosted ones are coming through satis; I guess I'm just to much of a n00b to really understand the (somewhat short) docs!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the files from the repository using:

```
git archive HEAD | gzip > archive.tar.gz
```

This will lose any git history, and essentially what you get on extracting this will not be a git tree at all.
If you want to turn this into a fresh tree to keep track of changes from this point on, you can do a git init in this directory and start fresh.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, but I'm specifically wanting to configure composer to do this for me... if it's possible.

Comment: I haven't used composer, but taking the quickest of looks, doesn't sounds like it would do this..but don't quote me!