# How to protect passwords given inside PHP so people browsing the code will not see it

Tags: php, security, passwords, password-protection

I am making a PHP script that people will have to purchase.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "planeub9_airmanagemembership";
    $dbuser = "planeub9_malcolm";
    $dbpass = "mypassword";

    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
?>
```

Is there any way that the db password can be hidden from plain view?

Comment: You cannot let people connect to a database without letting them connect to the database.

Comment: @SLaks That being said, surely there must be *some* alternative mechanism now than throwing plaintext passwords around in PHP files?

Comment: @user2864740: Not if you're distributing the source.

Comment: @SLaks Granted, I only use ASP.NET, but it trivially supports web.config (which is "secured" and controlled *independently* of the source), and if I really wanted I could enable encrypted connection strings.. *nothing* like that for PHP?

Comment: impossible to make this 100% secure...

Comment: If people are purchasing it, shouldn't they put in their own password and connect to their own database? Also, why are you using the super old, totally antiquated `mysql_query` method?

Comment: The general way is to supply a tarball containing an example configuration file, and to add an ignore command against your real configuration file into your version control system. When deploying their own app, the user must copy the example file to the correct name (e.g. "config.php.example" => "config.php") and fill in the blanks.

Comment: I hope you're not proposing to sell new code using the deprecated `mysql_*()` functions? You should migrate to `mysqli_*()` at the very least.

Comment: @user2864740: Not if you want to distribute the source to other people & let them run it.

Comment: @halfer Could you possibly give me the link to a tutorial on that? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: @tadman I didn't know it was so ancient :). What other options are there? I'm still pretty new to PHP.

Comment: @halfer I'm using Git.

Comment: @malcolmmcswain http://bit.ly/LRtXQd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will start with assuming you would like to release a tarball or zipfile of your software project, rather than granting access to your whole Git repository. To do this, you can use something like [`git archive`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) to create a release of your project.

Before you do this, you need to ensure that your configuration file is not committed to version control. If it is already, then copy it (for example copy "/config/base.php" to "/config/base.php.example") and reset all the settings to dummy values prior to committing it. Then remove the real config file from version control whilst leaving the physical file on disk.

To prevent this file coming up in your `git status` as uncommitted, add "/config/base.php" into your ".gitignore" file. This will help prevent you accidentally re-committing it too. Finally, add some instructions in your "README" to explain that "base.php" needs to be created as a copy of "base.php.example".

---

Now, if you wish to release the whole repo *and* you have already committed your configuration file, you have two options. Firstly, you can take the above advice about removing it from the repo now, and then change your database credentials. This will leave your private details in the repo, but they will be out-of-date and thus harmless.

Or, you can excise the configuration file from your repo entirely using `git rebase`. This causes problems if you have `push`ed the project to other contributors, who will have to `pull` a fresh copy and re-apply any pending changes. However, to remove something entirely from history, it is unavoidable (and if you let your collaborators know what is going on, quite easy to manage).