# Export all Git branches into individual zip files for each branch

Tags: git, export

I am looking for a way to export a Git repository so that I get a zip or directory for each branch individually.

This is similar to [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export), but instead of a zip of the **current** branch I am hoping to get a zip for **every** branch.

Is there a Git or Bash command that could do this?

Comment: As pointed out in [toydarian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24371664/456814), `git archive` can accept a branch name to export as an argument, so you just need to write a script that loops through the branch names and passes them to `git archive`, like toydarian has done.

Comment: I was asking for a command because I was hoping an OS agnostic method existed. Scripts like toydarians are useful, but wont run on windows. Yes, I could write a windows-compatible one, but I wanted to find out if a normal command could do it; it looks like the answer is no.

Comment: You say it won't run on Windows, and yet you asked specifically for a Bash command. Are you using Git Bash? It should work as long as you use Git Bash, even on Windows.

Comment: I am using Git bash. It does not work. `$ for f in ${$(git branch)[@]:1}; do; git archive --format zip --output /out/${f}.zip $f; done
sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token `;'`

Comment: There's probably a syntax mistake somewhere in the first line (Bash for loops will work in Windows Git Bash), I'm working on an alternative...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use `git archive` with a branch argument

`git archive` can accept a branch name to export as an argument, so you just need to write a script that loops through the branch names and passes them to git `archive`. For example, this will work in Windows Git Bash:

```bash
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
while read branch; do
  git archive --format zip --output <outputDirectory>/${branch}.zip $branch
done
```

I modified it from the 2<sup>nd</sup> example in the [official Linux Kernel documentation for `git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html#_examples).

### Breakdown

```bash
$ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads
foo
master
```

`git for-each-ref` will list each local branch under `refs/heads`, using just the branch name with the `refname:short` format.

That output is piped into a Bash `while` loop, which then substitutes the branch name for the `git archive` arguments:

```
while read branch; do
  git archive --format zip --output <outputDirectory>/${branch}.zip $branch
done
```

### For-loop solution

Here's a Bash `for` loop solution, inspired by [toydarian's (non-working) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24371664/456814):

```bash
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads); do
  git archive --format zip --output <outputDirectory>/${branch}.zip $branch
done
```

### Documentation

- [git-for-each-ref(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html)
- [git-archive(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this script. Make sure you checked out `master` before using the script!

```
for f in ${$(git branch)[@]:1}; do
    git archive --format zip --output /path/to/dir/${f}.zip $f
done
```

Here's the same commands in one line, to make it easier to copy, paste, and execute:

```
for f in ${$(git branch)[@]:1}; do; git archive --format zip --output /path/to/dir/${f}.zip $f; done
```

Comment: FYI, your commands won't work in Windows Git Bash, you probably have a syntax error somewhere: "`sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token ``;'`". That's the error the for the one-liner. "`sh.exe": ${$(git branch)[@]:1}: bad substitution`". That's the error for the first one.

Comment: Also note that you can actually copy, paste, and execute the first version of your command just fine, it shouldn't be necessary to put everything on one line in a terminal.

Comment: FYI, `git branch` is ill-suited to listing branches, unless you strip out the `*` that's listed next to the current branch, because `*` is interpreted as a file glob by `$()`, so it ends up expanding to all the files and directories in the current directory. It's one of Git's "porcelain" commands, vs a "plumbing" command like `git for-each-ref`, which is specifically made for scripting purposes, unlike `git branch`.