# How to extract the source files from a git repository?

Tags: git

I am very new to Git, but spent far too much time trying to achieve this. We had a contractor to do it for us a year ago for us, so unless i am missing something, this is doable.

We have a git repository (only the project.git and .git directories)
this project is a custom website. So we need to extract all the files from the repository to be able to deploy the site.

I can see a lot of objects, but obviously nothing which i was expecting (.aspx files etc...)

So what is the process to get the files out of the repository?

Let me know if I haven't been clear

Comment: simply clone it? `git clone /path/to/project.git`

Comment: You can look at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Comment: Having only the `.git` directory isn't what I would expect either. This is not how you work with git. Someone deleted all the project's files and sent you just the repository control folder. You can try to restore the deleted files by running the command `git reset --hard` one level above the `.git` folder, it should re-create what was deleted based on the commited data.

Comment: @Havenard it might be a bare repo, which makes the most sense for a backup. git clone should fix the issue.

Comment: @metacubed (and Havenard) yes indeed. From the solution i have picked from thirtythreeforty, it was a bare repo. Using the CLI instead of the GUI fixed y issue. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your contractor left you a *[bare repository](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/).*  It is used by Git for remotes that don't have a working copy (for example, on a server).

Just clone from the bare repository:

```
git clone project.git
```

You should end up with a directory called `project` that has a checkout of the `master` branch and a `.git` directory with a clone of the repo.  This `project` directory is a full copy of the repo, but it's the kind you can do useful things with.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know that we could use clone this way. I initially used the GUI and the clone was not extracting that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Absolute legend! Saved me 723 hours.

Answer (score 5):

The terminology `git` uses for this is *clone* and it means to make a copy of the repository in the current directory.

For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/path/to/project
```

Optionally you can specify a target directory and put your project there like so

```
git clone https://github.com/path/to/project path/to/directory
```

[From Git's documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).

Comment: Note, you don't have to use a GitHub remote.  A bare repository folder works just as well as a source.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you just want to get all the files out of the repository without creating a new one by cloning, you could just use `git archive`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) or [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) on how to use it.

If you need something other than the `master` branch, you can get a list by using `git branch`  (documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)).