# Git: create a new branch from a commit, delete everythng else

Tags: git, git-branch

What exactly should I do in order to

- create a new branch from a certain commit (`git checkout -b new_one; git cherry-pick commit_id`, am I right?)
- delete everything else
- rename branch `new_one` to `master`?

Of course, any change should be also pushed to remote.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to reset master to some known commit?

Comment: I want to obtain a fresh new master with only one commit (which was commit_id in the old master)

Answer (score 2):

In order to obtain a fresh master that only holds one commit, the easiest is to create a fresh repo and then put the current state of `master` into it as initial state. Otherwise, you'll always have the history of `master` present:

1. Export the current state of master (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/163769/520162)
   `git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master`
2. unzip the created zip file where your new repo shall be present
3. Initialize a new repo in that directory:
   `git init .`
4. Create your initial commit:
   `git add . && git commit -m "initial"`
5. Assign your `remote`:
   `git remote add ...`
6. push the new state of `master` there:
   `git push -f origin master:master`

Then, your repo will have only one branch (`master`) with only one commit.

Answer (score 1):

Create `new_branch` starting it off `commit_id`:

```
git branch new_branch commit_id
```

Check out to it:

```
git checkout new_branch
```

Delete old `master` branch:

```
git branch -d master   # you may need to use -D, with history loss may occur
```

Rename `new_branch` to `master`:

```
git branch -m new_branch master
```

Note that this does not necessarily remove all history - even if you perform full garbage collection, any objects that `commit_id` was referring to will remain in git history (and git object store).

Comment: But that is actually the point of my question: to remove history :).

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
git branch tmp <the very first commit in the repo>
git checkout tmp
git merge --squash <commit_id>
git branch -d master
git branch -m tmp master
```

... followed by a forced push

Comment: First, you obviously need to `git checkout tmp` after the first step. Second, these commands still leave you with a repo with the only commit, which is the very first commit. Which is not what I was asking about (yes, you still can add, commit and push actual files anew, but I think there should be a simpler way, shouldn't it?)

Comment: Yes, you do need to checkout tmp. I fixed that. Merge --squash will merge <commit_id> to tmp and create one single commit on tmp containing everything in <commit_id>.