# Need advice on versioning system

Tags: git, controls, versioning

So I've used a lot of git.

Lately I've taken up modding a game, and the base framework I need to monitory for changes/additions is quite large.

However when it comes to distributing any mod I create, I don't need or want to ship the entire assets...

I know I can use git, fork the main branch, then diff the two when my mod is done.

I just want to know if anyone has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use git archive and pipe it to a tar/zip command (as suggested here: [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)), but adding with the branch name, the location of your mod

```
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip yourbranch folder/containing/your/mod
```

So you can end with your mod at a specific branch/other git object state, without having all the rest of the project.

**Update**

This command did put me alone the right search path and I came across this working command in another stack thread.

```
git archive --format zip -o export.zip head $(git diff --name-only master head)
```

Comment: Hmm this does work but I will have to keep a manifest of all my files, and at that point a simple shell script would work.

Its an issue, because its not '/game/mods/mymod'.
I have to follow the same directory structure as the game assets (mostly), so that means picking out many files all over the place.

Comment: I actually found a solution and updated this answer.