# Git export achive directly from origin

Tags: php, git, zip, archive

I would like to create a simple script, that will download plugins from remote repositories into directory. I have an array of URLs, to git files on remote server - like this one from GitHub https://github.com/nette/sandbox.git. GitHub has support for downloading ZIP archives but I have plugins from **many other repositories** which doesn't offer this option.

Back to my question - is there any option how to get the archive instead of downloading full repository and exporting archive from it using git in command line? I have found this question - [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) - but this wouldn't be possible using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

this [post](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/29/exporting-your-repository.html) gives you details about exporting git in the way you mentioned .

> git archive HEAD --format=zip > archive.zip
>
> You can also archive a remote using the --remote= option. Just
>   be aware that this does not work with GitHub remotes, as they
>   encourage you to use the download button instead. With any other
>   remote it should work fine though, and check the manpage if you’re
>   having issues.

but the problem with this method is when i tried it with  both **github** and **bitbuck** i got `remote doesn't support protocol` error .

---

i just wrote code for a generic solution on my machine and its working for me . let me share it with you . you can execute shell command using php using [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) .

```
<?php 

//clearing a folder named test if it exist(avoiding git errors) 
shell_exec('rm -rf test');

//cloning into test folder
shell_exec('git clone https://github.com/nette/sandbox.git test');

//archiving
shell_exec('cd test && git archive HEAD --format=zip > archive.zip');

//copying to root folder
shell_exec('cp test/archive.zip archive.zip');

//removing the temp test folder we created
shell_exec('rm -rf test');

?>
```

**shell_exec** won't work if php **safemode** is turned on . you might require setting appropriate permissions for the script etc . but i think this an idea to start with php, for getting what you want.