# It there a built in Git command for checking out a Git ref or branch into a non git directory?

Tags: git, git-checkout, working-directory

I am compiling source from a local git mirror in a separate directory, ie I don't do any work in the  Git directory, I just need the source code from it.

Of course I go into the Git directory, check out the ref I want and copy it into the compilation directory, but I want to know if there is a git command for doing it directly

Something along the lines of:

```
git checkout file://home/user/repo.get treeish  /my/working/directory
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/160608/978525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a command which can extract a tree from the repository,
but the git archive command can create a tarball (or other format) of the tree at a given commit:

```
git archive --format=tar <commit-id> > project.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the LAST commit, a `git clone --depth 1` could do the trick also...