# Git: how to copy only the versioned files from a subdirectory?

Tags: git

### Problem

I have a git repo with two subdirectories under the root `:/a` and `:/b`, and I want to copy all *versioned* files from `:/a` into `:/a-copy`.

Essentially, I'd like to do

```
git mv a a-copy
```

without actually moving `a`.

### More Details

There are also many non-versioned files in `:/a`, and I don't want to delete them, so I can't simply do

```
git clean -df a
cp -r a a-copy
```

The best workaround I've found (on Linux) is

```
mkdir a-copy
cd a
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -i cp --parents {} ../a-copy
```

but I hope there is a simpler way.

### Is This Question a Duplicate of "[Do a “git export” (like “svn export”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)"?

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) is similar, but it only covers the case of copying/exporting the **entire** repo. I only want to copy **part of** the repo, i.e. the files under `:/a`, and not also the files under `:/b`. I read that question and its answers before posting this question. Now that I have an answer to my question, I see that the `git archive` based solutions to that other question also solve my problem here.

Comment: Why don't you just `clone` it again? Why does it matter if you then have to delete some of the result? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I updated the question with more emphasis on the problem I'm trying to solve. If I simply use `cp -r`, then "deleting some of the result" is not easy, since I have to manually delete the unversioned files (there are many). Yes, `git clone` following by `cp -r` will work, but that seems like another overly complicated work around. I would expect there to be a simple, built in way to do this, similar to `git archive` or `git checkout-index`.

Comment: *"I want to copy all versioned files from `:/a` into `:/a-copy`"* - ...why?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: because I'm forking the development under `:/a`.

Comment: Nor sure quite what you mean by that. Why not make it a submodule, it it will have a separate lifecycle?

Comment: *if. Or make it a dependency and separate it entirely. This could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I don't think it's an XY problem. Let me try to be more concrete. Here `:/a` is something like `:/test/a` and I'm creating a new test `:/test/similar-to-a` which is similar to `:/test/a`. The two tests are similar enough that I want to copy `:/test/a` to get started, but creating an abstraction `:/test/generic-a` from which `:/test/a` and `:/test/simlar-to-a` are derived would be unnecessary abstraction / over engineering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121285/discussion-between-ntc2-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 4):

The command sequence you are looking for is:

```
git archive HEAD a | tar -x -C /tmp
mv /tmp/a b
```

or equivalently

```
cd a
git archive --prefix=b/ HEAD . | tar -x -C ..
```

[`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) creates a `tar` archive using that contains the files from the `a` subdirectory. It uses the versions of these files from the `HEAD` revision; you can specify an other `Git` revision if you prefer.

The archive is written to `stdout` and it goes through the pipe (`|`) to the [`tar`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/tar1.html) program that extracts the files (`-x`) and puts them into the directory `/tmp` (`-C`).

Because `Git` adds the files together with their enclosing directory (`a`), `tar` creates the directory `a` into `/tmp` and it contains the files you want.

You use `mv` to move (and rename) `/tmp/a` and place it where you need it.

Comment: Thanks! That is definitely simpler, and allows me to only get the committed versions (at any revision) without having to `git stash` or `git checkout` first.