# How to ignore '.git' folder when clone the project from github and zipping it from my local

Tags: jenkins, command-line, zip, 7zip

Here is what i am doing.

**1) Cloning my project from github to local machine.**

"git clone https://github.com/xxxxxx/QACODE.git"

**2) Then i am trying to zip my project through commandline.**

"7z a QACODE C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/workbench/*"

**3) And this is what i am seeing in the compressed folder.**

[image: the .git folder i don't want to zip with. so suggest me a way to ignore .git folder from my zip file]

Comment: `git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master` https://stackoverflow.com/a/163769/2779152

Comment: awesome!! thanks @madebydavid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah it did works 
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master