# How can I export a git repo?

Tags: git, export

Pursuant to this: [Do a “git export” (like “svn export”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export), what's wrong with this picture?:

```
user@machine /cygdrive/c/Ws/PROJECT_master_coverage : git archive master | bzip2 > /cygdrive/c/Ws/PROJECT_master_coverage.tar.bz2
fatal: Not a valid object name

user@machine /cygdrive/c/Ws/PROJECT_master_coverage : git archive --format zip --output /cygdrive/c/Ws/PROJECT_master_coverage.zip master
fatal: Not a valid object name

user@machine /cygdrive/c/Ws/PROJECT_master_coverage : git archive master | tar -x -C /cygdrive/c/Ws/PROJECT_master_coverage.tgz
fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: If this is not a bare repo, try: `GIT_DIR=.git git archive master`, just for testing.

Comment: Does the repo have `master` branch at all?

Comment: The soution I applied was to clone a new one and then do rm -rf ${project_root}/.git/  ;-) Then tar cvzf project.tgz ${project_root}