# Get a copy of code of a particular commit of a local git repository?

Tags: git

I have a folder with local git repository. And I have a lot of comments, but no remote repository yet.

```
git log
```

shows a lot of comments with commit hash values.

Now I need to get a copy of a particular comment and save the source files in another directory. What's the best way to do it? `git checkout HASH` will overwrite the current directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export This might help

Comment: Use `git archive` if you just want a raw tarball or zip file. Use `git worktree add` to add a work-tree with a detached HEAD or new branch pointing to that commit if you want to do actual work with it, and have a Git new enough to support `git worktree` (2.5 or later). Beware of various bugs in `git worktree` if you are going to work on this for a while; in this case, you might want a new clone.

Answer (score 0):

`git archive` is your friend in this case