# Packing up a directory under version control of git

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

If I want to zip a directory up from my git repository will it contain git messages?

How would I export a directory without any version control?

If possible if it's a feature from Github.

I have found and linked to this post but it is not clear if it's the same thing as I'm asking and it's from 2008:
[Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Can I simply copy the directories locally? It's the root directory that has a hidden version control folder correct?

I found git-archive that makes a zip: 
https://alvinalexander.com/git/git-export-project-archive-cvs-svn-export

Comment: Use `git-archive`

Comment: I just found a good post on `git-archive`. I can export to a zip and then unzip and copy the directories I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I linked to that in my post. Please remove the duplicate.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts you found an answer to your question and instead of trying that out you made a duplicate question. I don't see a need for both questions so I'm leaving my close vote up.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez What are you talking about? I linked to it, I said it didn't quite answer my question and explained that. My question is different in that I want a specific directory and that I don't know about svn export and how it compares.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to zip a directory up from my git repository will it contain git messages?

If your zip file contains the `.git` folder, yes it will. If the `.git` folder is not present, then the commit messages will not be contained. However, unless you also remove `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes` and `.gitmodules` files, someone will be able to tell that it was once tracked through git.

> How would I export a directory without any version control?

Just use `git archive` [1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), as also linked in the duplicate question [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163769/461597). If you just want a subdirectory, you may zip that directly.

> If possible if it's a feature from Github.

Here is how you can create releases on GitHub: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-releases After doing this, you can automatically download the repository as a Zip or Tar file. Exactly what you want!

> I have found and linked to this post but it is not clear if it's the same thing as I'm asking and it's from 2008:
>      Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?

Yes, your question is mostly a duplicate.

> Can I simply copy the directories locally? It's the root directory that has a hidden version control folder correct?
>   Yes, this is correct. All the version data is stored inside the root's `.git` folder.
>
> I found git-archive that makes a zip: https://alvinalexander.com/git/git-export-project-archive-cvs-svn-export

Just use the builtin `git archive` tool for that.