# alternative to git archive for exporting

Tags: git

I have been using `git` for ages but there are some things that just don't click for me.

As part of my normal build system, I need to export a specific tag into a temporary source directory and the only way I've found to do this is by using `git archive`.

Specifically:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git archive #{internal_version} --format=zip > #{$temp_source_code_path}/code.zip`

This is stupid as I first need to zip the entire thing and then unzip it before building it.

The actual git repository is local and the command is run from it.

Is there a better (**faster**) way of doing this?

Best regards,

Frank

Comment: If this temporary source directory is also a git repository, you could fetch the tag with `--depth=1` from any repository which holds the tag.

Comment: You could create a detached working tree in a temporary directory with: `git worktree add -d ../temp tagname`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone a local repository just like you would a remote one:

```sh
git clone /path/to/your/repo /path/to/build/dir
```

Then, whenever you need to build, you can run

```sh
cd /path/to/build/dir
git pull
# Run build script
```

This has the added benefit that it'll only copy over changes, rather than archiving the entire repository.

That being said, `rsync` might be a more appropriate tool

Comment: Thanks. The directory is deleted each time and is exported to from different repositories so using `git pull` does not quite work for my scenario, but I have use `git clone ${repository_path} --branch TAG` and that is much faster than doing the zip and unzip.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible ways :

- use [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)
- checkout to a new location using [`GIT_DIR=path/to/.git` and `GIT_WORKTREE=path/to/checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_the_git_repository)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export files from git without creating an intermediate archive, you can pipe the data through `tar` directly:

```
git archive master | tar xC /some/path
```

If you want to be able to perform git operations in the directory where the files are exported, consider using `git clone` or `git worktree` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `git clone` just for the sake of performance even though I can't quite use it as Alectro suggested it.